# Upvotes that "cancel out" downvotes

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes, zero-voted-posts

Sometimes I see that someone has downvoted a question or an answer that I don't think deserved to be downvoted. I don't think it deserves to be upvoted either, yet I find myself tempted to upvote it just to "cancel out" the unwarranted (IMO) downvote.

Should we be discouraging this practice? If so, how might we do so and what might we encourage users to do instead?

**UPDATE** (in response to @Louis's comment) : Sure, but a voting metric is most meaningful when we can trust systemically that all instances of it are "saying" more or less the same thing: An upvote is supposed to say *"this is a good answer"*. One that says *"this is not a bad answer"* is saying a different thing entirely. If both of these things are being said through the same metric, and if this is occurring on a wide-enough scale, the meaningfulness of that metric begins to degrade - our ability to understand what is being said through it (what it *means*) grows decreasingly clear.

I acknowledge that this is a hypothetical problem (because I assume relatively few users do it), and therefore that this is largely a theoretical discussion, but I think the basic idea and utility of not only Stack Overflow but Stack Exchange is predicated on the clarity and meaningfulness of these metrics, and therefore that its a worthwhile discussion to have.

Comment: Your votes are yours to use, use them as you may.

Comment: @Louis see update

Comment: per http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up *"Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!"* The operative word is **feel**, and it's directed at **you**.  I personally think upvotes should be a result of the post quality, not as a result of a post not "deserving" a downvote.  But that's just how I use my votes.

Comment: I just upvoted this question to cancel a downvote.

Comment: @WarrenDew I know this is Meta, but really?

Comment: What I love even more is when 5 people all upvote to cancel a *single* downvote.

Comment: @Louis - I hear your argument, and I actually agree with it, but it's not relevant to what I'm trying to discuss: You're thinking about this from the standpoint of the *user* while I'm thinking about it from the standpoint of the system: I'm not asking what *I* as a user should do myself, but what *users* should be encouraged to do generally that will maximize the meaningfulness of the metrics.

Comment: This can also be viewed as a deterrent to punitive downvoting - if your downvote is likely to be viewed as unfair, it's likely to trigger an upvote.  The effect on the question's appearance is neutral, but the poster gets +8 net reputation - a result that might be worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Upvotes aren't meant to be used to "cancel" someone else's downvotes. You're using a vote based on the merit of another vote, rather than the merit of the post itself (which is a vote's intended usage). If a post ***trully, really*** doesn't "deserve" a downvote, then someone who actually thinks the post is good will vote the other way, and everything will work out. You break the voting system by voting based on other votes, instead of voting based on posts themselves. If you wouldn't upvote a post normally, then don't upvote it just because someone else downvotes it.

Comment: An equally odious practice is what I call a "sheep vote" - where someone EITHER sees that a question/answer has many upvotes, decides it must be good because of the votes, and adds their own upvote; OR sees that a question/answer has many downvotes, decides that it must be bad because of the votes, and adds their own downvote.  Ironically, there don't seem to be enough "cancelling voters" in the community to cancel out the "sheep voters".

Comment: @DavidWallace - "sheep voting" is even worse in the close queue.

Comment: Like it or not, down votes *ARE* used for punishment and vengeance.  These obscure the technical merit of the content and SHOULD be cancelled.

Comment: Also see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). I often use upvotes on questionable questions to help balance all the negativity of "hunting in packs" (sans a *really* bad question).

Comment: Just curious: suppose you see a question or answer with score `-1` which you feel did not deserve a downvote. Would you still be tempted to make a "cancel out" vote if you viewed the vote count and saw there were 10 upvotes and 11 downvotes?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74666

Comment: There appears to be a special kind of people out there who quickly down vote questions they do not understand. If I see a clever question and downvotes combined with comments which clearly show those people did not understand the question, I use counter-upvoting.

Comment: @user2225104: So, you are saying if you see a worthwhile question that's downvoted, you'll upvote it despite the downvotes? What does that have to do with voting on meh questions because you don't think it deserves a negative score?

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, there are actually questions out there, which require some thinking and maybe insider knowledge to a specific domain/industry to actually appreciate the depth. Just as there are "too stupid" questions, there are questions beyond some peoples grasp. Especially if they try to harvest reputation and feel offended that they would actually have to spend time on those. Those I counter- upvote (if in those cases I happen to be one of the lucky ones who get it). In cases where I am sitting in the dark, I usually keep the question open and see what happens, instead of downvoting.

Comment: @user2225104: Why do you call it counter-voting when you vote acording to the posts merits, even if the majority to date disagreed with you? Or is that not what you said? And if that's what you said, how is it relevant that you vote different from the majority in some cases, as long as you vote according to the posts merits disregarding any other votes?

Comment: @Deduplicator I like to think that if a vote has -3 or so, those 3 people are not the majority but only some individuals who got it wrong. My upvote then fixes that "bug". The majority has not uttered their opinion (yet) at that point. Usually new questions collect some 16-30 views rather quickly. My thought process in that situation is something like "Hey - that question is not wrong or stupid or in violation of the format!". And up it goes....

Comment: It's important to realize that upvotes award more reputation than downvotes remove. If you see a post with -2 score and think to yourself "hey, this is not worth -2 score!", you are giving the poster a positive gain in reputation if you upvote, despite a negative score. Many times I have seen completely stupid wrong answers get left around because somebody feels the need to come along and cancel out up to 5 downvotes with their 1 upvote. On an answer, those downvotes cost the voter reputation. Answers do not get an 'A' for effort.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if instead of showing the numerical sum of the up and down votes, both were shown (like on YouTube). I have watched my rep go up and down on a controversial question recently, and yet the overall question score stayed at Zero. I can't (or don't know how to) see the separate totals of up and down unless I look at my profile. But some questions seem to be hotly contested yet hover near zero... ??? Show me the votes. Why isn't this already true? Every public vote I have ever seen shows the votes for both (or all) sides, not a Sum.

Comment: @nocomprende - you can see the up/down totals when you get > 1000* rep. *not sure about the actual number

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This practice is absolutely odious, and should be banned. (**Edit** by "banned" I mean, that people should be firmly instructed not to do it.  I don't mean to imply that the SO developers should come up with some kind of AI solution that magically intuits the mindset and intentions of every voter.)

You should vote based on the **merits of the question or answer** that you're voting on. If you vote to "cancel out" other people's opinions, you make a mockery of the whole voting process.

Effectively, when you cast a "cancelling vote", what you're saying is "I don't feel strongly about this question/answer, but my half-hearted opinion is worth more than the genuine opinion of the person who cast the first vote".  How incredibly arrogant!

Often, it seems to happen when the downvoter has explained the reason for the downvote, and the "cancelling voter" hasn't bothered to fully understand the reason.

Another likely scenario is that if the question doesn't really deserve a downvote, then the downvoter will think about it, change his/her mind, and remove the downvote. I've done that a few times. Then, you're stuck with an upvote on a question that doesn't deserve it.

Yet another very frequent scenario is that someone downvotes an incorrect solution, and posts a comment explaining why it's incorrect.  The respondent sees the comment and corrects the solution; and the downvoter removes their vote.  Meanwhile, someone posts a "cancelling upvote", which doesn't get removed.  So the respondent is effectively rewarded for having got their solution "wrong first time".

Please STOP with the "cancelling votes". This practice is absolutely odious.

Comment: I agree entirely. That's why I posted this question. I thought I could make the most effective argument by framing it in the rationale of someone doing it, while pointing out the problem it creates systemically. Your answer, which provides a more tangible and practical illustration of the problem, is welcome. +1, but I'll leave it unaccepted for now to promote further discussion.

Comment: Banned?  How?  That beside the point, your vote is yours to use for any reason.

Comment: "Any reason"?  So it should be acceptable for me to go through and upvote all questions that begin with the letter "A" and downvote all questions that begin with the letter "B"?

Comment: Is that your preference?

Comment: Absolutely.  I loathe the letter "B".

Comment: *and if everyone did that, votes would be meaningless, and SO wouldn't work* That's the whole point I've been trying to make.

Comment: You should have picked another nit, systematic voting for a particular user.  That is in fact banned.  How do you propose to ban  your situation?  BTW, I disagree with the characterization of "absolutely odious."  There are much worse things going on on SO.  Thus, I downvoted your answer *to cancel out an upvote!*

Comment: Look, I know that a ban is not really possible.  Just like littering is illegal ("banned") in most cities, but we can't stop people doing it.  Perhaps "strongly discouraged" would have been a better way of putting it.

Comment: I acknowledge that this is nitpicky, and I don't have a specific solution. It's my understanding that meta is a place to *discuss* nits, whether they are valid, if so whether they warrant solutions, and if so what those solutions might be. The idea that the suggestion of a problem is invalid if we cant jump directly to a concrete solution undermines the whole idea of meta. This isn't SO.

Comment: The odious practice is the culture of derogatory downvoting here on SO. While that goes on, you'll get resistance by tactical upvoting. And, of course, you will never in a million years be able to figure out whether someone upvoted on the merits or on principle (unless s/he tells you in a comment).

Comment: @einpoklum Can you please clarify what you mean by "derogatory downvoting"?  In what circumstances would you call a downvote derogatory, and in what circumstances would you call it not derogatory?

Comment: What if answer/question has been edited to perfection, yet downvotes persist. A user, oblivious to the history of the post might see that as injustice and may try to cancel out.

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi Yes, and three others may all do the same.  So the respondent ends up with +38 points, as a reward for failing to get things right the first time around.  Much better if people JUST DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: I think this answer misses out on a lot of points, including human nature. The failure is not in people using upvotes to cancel downvotes. The failure is in the voting system itself; you are projecting a high dimensional space onto a one dimensional (upvote or downvote) space. Of course there are going to be misunderstandings. I firmly believe downvotes should simply be invisible to everyone but the author of the question as to not bias other possible answers but to give the author feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I believe SO upvotes and downvotes aren't uniform in their meaning *already*, in my opinion: Many people upvote questions to imply "I also encountered a similar issue"; others upvote to imply "you've presented this issue in a thought-provoking way"; others' upvote implies "I believe this is a fundamental question which needs to be answered on SO". I could make a similar listing for answers). **This is not necessarily a bad thing** (although it has effects I disapprove of, such as massive upvoting of nearly-trivial questions whose answer is on the first page of the relevant fine manual, as opposed to well-thought-out questions on finer points of advanced issues.)

As for downvotes, here, in addition to legitimate reasons for downvoting a question, there seem to be numerous mean-spirited and inappropriate reasons for downvoting, again in my opinion. This is a bad thing, I would claim, but it's a question of social norms of the community. I find there's too much of a "downvoting culture" on SO - as opposed to other SX sites (e.g. see [this question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187812/196834)) - and many of us want to mitigate this effect.

Comment: TL;DR: There are lots of reasons to upvote, and thus voting is broken. And I hate downvotes, and thus I try to cancel as many as possible. Is that a correct summary?

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, I never said voting was broken. Let me emphasize that. Also - seriously? Two paragraphs are TL;DR for you?

Comment: Not really tldr, more trying to reformulate to make sure I understood you properly. Well, now I only take issue with explicit counter-voting. And how does downvoting question which deserve it amount to a bad culture? If anything, there are too few doing that, probably in order to "be nice" (in the most unhelpful way they could find).

Comment: @Deduplicator: The bad culture is in seeing a whole damn lot more questions as "deserving it" than other communities would.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you believe that postings (questions and answers) should be upvoted whenever somebody thought they were bad enough to downvote.  Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @DavidWallace: You have misunderstood. It was pretty clear before, but I've also re-edited.

Comment: Please elaborate *how* you want to mitigate it. And what those "mean-spirited and inappropriate reasons for downvoting" are. Because that's the only interesting part.

Comment: @Deduplicator: While I appreciate your request, that would be another entire discussion which I believe that 1. Has been held elsewhere on meta and 2. Would take a lot of time and emotional attention I can't spend on the site right now.

Answer (score -1):

I have to say I completely agree, I was infact about to ask the same question until I saw you had already asked it.

What got me thinking about it was this post: 
[What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

In it he asks why a specific question ([How to get string before .(dot) and after /(last) slash in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557870/how-to-get-string-before-dot-and-after-last-slash-in-java)) has recieved so many downvotes. However when I looked at the question I saw it now has 4 upvotes. Clearly some of the large amount of people who viewed the first post must have agreed with him and cancelled out the downvotes.

I agree we probably shouldn't vote on questions we don't understand, but voting a reasonable question down for no reason is worse, and I always try to cancel these mean votes out.

If anything the main reason I think its ok to cancel out unworthy downvotes is because I know that when I first joined if my question had been downvoted for no reason, I would have assumed this sort of negativity was standard for SO, and I wouldn't have come back.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this +4 absolutely-no-effort-whatsoever question. I downvoted it to cancel the upvotes that were cast to cancel the initial downvotes.

Comment: Thats ok, I upvoted it to cancel out your downvote :)
This sort of spiteful voting is exactly what I am talking about, its a perfectly valid question that 5 people were happy to help out with. If the people who know about the subject don't think its a bad question then what right do you have it say it is.

Comment: Who says I don't know anything about the subject? :) Seriously, though, the question in its integrality is *I have String like this `"core/pages/viewemployee.jsff"` from this code I need to get "viewemployee". How to get this in java?* No research, no code, no nothing. This is not, never has been and hopefully never will be a *valid* question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but 5 people have answered it and now its a good post that could help many people. Sure the answers deserve the upvotes and not the question, but if the question is downvoted too much it won't be noticed by the people who could really use it.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to disagree again, but how is it a good post "now"? The quality of the answers does not affect the quality of the question. Your edit did not improve it much, not that you can add the missing research effort anyway. And people can still use downvoted questions, it's not like they're deleted (although that one could be without the community losing much, I'm afraid).

Comment: Not even the existence of an *accepted* answer indicates a question is a good question:

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable

Comment: I agree with your post about unanswerable questions, all I'm saying is that if a question has helped people it can't be that bad. Surely the whole point of this site is to help people, otherwise its just about meaningless points.