# Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, accepted-answer, needs-more-focus, unclear

Some of the close reasons essentially assert that providing an answer for a question, within the format of SO, is impossible. Those are the close reasons of *unclear what you are asking*, *lacks sufficient information* and *too broad* (the latter for the case of answers being too long rather than too numerous). Can a question be legitimately closed using those reasons if it has answers? What about if it has an accepted answer?

After all, it could be argued that if someone was able to produce a short answer to the OP's question that the OP accepted, the OP *must* have provided sufficient clear information.

(I assert that yes, it is legitimate to close answered questions with those close reasons. I'm asking a rhetorical question)

Comment: The original poster is sometimes the last person able to correctly select a correct answer. Ergo the mere existence of an accepted answer isn't in itself an *automatic* reason not to close.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Remember, [we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.](https://stackoverflow.com/about)

A library is no good if you can't find anything, and by the same token there's no reason to keep questions around if the answers can't be found by the next person with the same problem.

Just because the asker got what he needed doesn't mean he expressed his need clearly; [as I wrote just the other day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/258062#258062),

> Yes, any reasonably-competent programmer familiar with the topic can [daniel their way to a solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/258062#258062), but *your* ability to synthesize a problem statement where none is provided is no more an indication of clarity than is *your* ability to mentally insert missing letters into "[Aoccdrnig to rscheearch at Cmabrigde uinervtisy](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/aoccdrnig-to-rscheearch)".

The easy solution here is for answerers who wish their answers to remain attached to open, not-deleted questions to **edit the questions they're answering** such that they're clear and easy for future readers to find. If they don't wish to do so, then they must be content with helping just the one person...

Comment: In some cases I've edited unclear questions in light of the answer the OP accepted,  to clarify what the OP must really have meant.

Comment: Why, it sounds like you are arguing for the return of the *Too Localised* close reason ;-)

Comment: Except TL refers to questions that will objectively help no one else, whereas unclear refers to questions that will only help the OP because only the OP has any idea what they're saying and the answer just happened to guess it right.

Comment: Unclear to whom? I reject your premise out of hand because the chance of finding a poorly worded question is *always* higher than the chance of finding a deleted one. I have posed accepted answers to questions closed for alleged lack of clarity where I didn't find the question at all unclear. Others make find it unclear, but this merely means they think differently from me and the OP. They have no right to demand we conform to their preferred modes of thought. Cleaning up poor spelling  and phraseology in the question is another matter, there we agree.

Comment: Indeed, the fundamental oversight at the core of this answer is that far too many of these closing decisions reflect not the answerability of the question, but the voter's lack of familiarity with the subject matter.  The reading audience of questions is those with the background familiarity to discuss their subject matter, not random passers by who hail from other corners of the development space.

Comment: I'm a big fan of folks [focusing on areas they have some knowledge in](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283428/remove-haskell-questions-from-review-audits/283479#283479) when moderating, @Chris - that's not always feasible, but certainly preferable. If you've ideas for encouraging this, post 'em up.

Comment: @Shog9 Very true. If people would limit their moderation to those questions that are about subjects they are familiar with it would make a big difference.

Comment: this answer assumes that all people speak the same technical language (that is false): the same (at the core) technical problem can be expressed in multiple different (at the surface) ways. Moreover, it is often half of the solution to translate a loose problem statement into the formal (math) problem statement that uses proper technical terms (the other half of the problem is to translate it to the desired programming language -- it may be trivial compared to the first half). Please, understand: people who need the solution may be aware only about the first problem statement (in human terms).

Comment: ..continued: instead of editing the question to replace loose human terms with a proper technical terms (formal model of the problem) that may prevent to find the question by people who need it the most, the question may be closed as a duplicate of a canonical question with a format problem statement (for people who already knows the half of the solution). If there is no duplicate; it can be created or the formal statement can be the part of the answer.