# What should be done with a question that was answered and then closed for reasons such as being unclear or being too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I have at least two questions that I asked that were closed or put on hold for being too broad or being unclear what the question was asking.  Both questions were answered, and in both cases, the answers were very good ones in my opinion that would help a lot of other people in addition to myself.

I have edited both of them to hopefully make them better questions, but I am unsure what to do at this point, as the closure/hold of at least one of them is really hurting me vote wise when combined with some other down votes, as I can no longer ask a question (banned from it).

Since they were both answered before being closed, is there any particular thing that should be done with them?  They were both answered very well in my opinion.

The questions are:  [How do I run a JUnit Test on the exception handlers of a method and when a function normally uses a file for input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171551/how-do-i-run-a-junit-test-on-the-exception-handlers-of-a-method-and-when-a-funct)

and

[What sources of data/parameters should I use when Unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151148/when-junit-testing-a-large-program-system-do-i-pass-values-to-methods-to-be-tes)

Comment: First thing would be to edit your posts (this and the other question) so it's not a wall of text.

Comment: Is that better for this one?

Comment: Much easier on the eyes, yes. It's really the simple changes (line new lines) that can help turn a negative post into a positive one.

Comment: I voted to re-open your second question. Your first question, though, is a different matter. You've strung together a number of issues which at first glance look like a series of different questions. My instinct would have been to close as too broad, but after the third or fourth reading I could see that you're really focussing on a specific aspect of testing, but have hidden it in so much verbiage. A simple example of what you're trying to test and an attempt at a unit test for it would have made things so much clearer. As it stands, 'unclear' would still get my vote.

Comment: related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable)

Answer (score 8):

You should do the exact same thing that you'd do if the questions weren't answered.  Make the unclear questions clearer and make the broad questions narrower.

The fact that someone posted an answer to an unclear question doesn't mean that the question is clear.  Some people are just really good at divining what is meant by an unclear question.  Other people just make a whole bunch of assumptions and make a guess at what they think is being asked.  Even if such a person ends up being right, it doesn't mean the question is clear, or that it shouldn't be fixed to *make* it clear.  The assistance of an answer may help you determine how to better convey what you're really asking though.

The fact that someone has posted an answer to a very broad question doesn't mean it's not too broad.  The most common situation here is that the answer isn't actually complete, and instead is only addressing a very small portion of the question asked.  If that is the only portion that you really care about, then you may be able to narrow the scope of the question to exclude the other content that couldn't be covered.

Comment: ok.  But would improving the question actually get it reopened since its already been answered?  (Also a long time ago I just realized, I ignorantly closed one of my own questions because it had been answered, whoops rofl).

Comment: You aren't speaking from the important thing. The important thing is, that there is practically no way to reopen an once closed question. Yes, I know, theoretically yes. But practically, none, because most of the reopen votes never ends or have a negative result. It is partially the problem of the system (there is no way to contact the people closed your question), and partially the moderators/reviewers (they are using your power often for unneeded hostility).

Comment: @PeterHorvath Before the reopen queue existed, yes, that was more or less true.  Now that we have a reopen queue that's simply not the case, and posts that get improved to the point of no longer meeting the close criteria can easily be reopened.

Comment: @Servy Your statements directly contradicts my experience. It is simply not so. Hostile closing of questions, marking similar questions as (exact) duplicates, it is quite common here. I really can't understand, what is the psychological background, what makes the misuse of the power so funny.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Classifying it as misuse is exactly the wrong attitude to have.  Could it be?  Maybe.  I sincerely doubt it, though.  Rather, look at it as a sign of needing improvement.  It's constructive criticism at it's core, and taking a hostile approach to what is, at its essence, feedback designed to help, doesn't do you, or anyone else, any good.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Sounds like you simply don't like the closing criteria, rather than that there are questions not meeting the close criteria that aren't being reopened.

Comment: Ok, the question that was closed, and I made better (and which I made better), is still closed, and even worse, just got voted down more.  After making many improvements.  I was on Servy's side of this argument, until that happened.  I fix it so it gets voted down further?!?!

Comment: @cluemein You're drawing a whole bunch of attention to your questions by posting about them here on meta.  They've been viewed by lots of people who could reopen the question if they felt that it merited reopening.  That they haven't indicates that they feel it shouldn't be reopened.  Getting a downvote indicates the same thing; people read the question and felt that, after the edit, it was not acceptable.

Comment: Well, have you read my question?  It seems to be quite clear, and not broad to me, and I made it less so now.  I am starting to feel that it is all chance now, and I might as well clear cookies and cache, and all other tracking, wait for my ip address to get renewed to a new one and make a new account.  Because if I make my questions better, and they simply get voted down for the heck of it (read what it was previously, it was improved, I put work into this), I really have no incentive to try improving my answers.  speaking hypothetically, not planning to, just illustrating the implications.

Comment: @cluemein Your second question is absolutely too broad, there's no question there in my mind.  The first question I don't understand the subject enough to judge whether or not it is clear.

Comment: I do not understand how it is unclear or too broad,  I narrowed it down as far as it goes.  Also, if you don't understand the other question, why judge the other, because though not the same question, its in the same topical area, or are we talking about different questions here?  For it to be less broad, it would be going into another dimension.  So please, really, explain how it is too broad, because I can't fathom this at all.

Comment: I have improved it multiple times, drastically, and its still to broad; what, does it fill the whole universe and I have to get it down to the width of an atom?

Comment: @cluemein You're asking how you want to approach testing a problem.  How is that *not* a broad question?  Even the answers make it clear that the question is too broad when they open up with "it depends".  They each had to make a whole bunch of assumptions to narrow the context themselves to provide a reasonably scoped answer, but since those assumptions aren't in the question, the answers are incomplete.  They'd need to cover all possibilities that they choose not to bring up to be complete answers.

Comment: @cluemein A quality, **complete** answer should be able to be posted in just a few paragraphs or less.  As it is, you're clearly not to that point.  The question is attracting incomplete answers precisely because it's too broad to answer completely.

Comment: It has a complete answer in my view, and is helpful.  I now just narrowed the question so much, that there are only two or three possible answers.  No question, none, can be narrower than that.  Otherwise we should all start flagging every question as too broad because by that logic, simply being a question makes it too broad.  And I am sorry for putting too many words in your view, but I like to be very very clear, very detailed, etc. etc.  I don't want to be unclear, deliberate irony there, as the other question was flagged for that.  So do we all start flagging every question in existence?

Comment: @cluemein The problem is that an answer to your question of "do A or B" cannot be answered with just "Do A".  It merits explanation.  Again, just because a given answer provides all you want to know doesn't mean it's a complete answer to the question.  If someone asks, "What should I do with my life" and someone answers, "become a programmer" the fact that an answer is provided doesn't mean that the question isn't broad.  The fact that the answer was acceptable to the person asking the question also doesn't mean the question or the answer are quality posts.

Comment: Its a very clear question with very clear answer.  The accepted answer is educational in relation to the question, very helpful and informative.  I think you just don't want to change your mind.  If you had believed the world was flat and I put you into space, you would still think it was flat through some contrived reason.  The answer was clear.  The answer successfully answered the now very narrow question, is educational, and if you disagree with that, I have to conclude that SO is truly lost, and I might as well stop giving a flip about quality, since it doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @cluemein I didn't say it wasn't clear.  I said it was too broad.  That you like the answer doesn't make the question not broad, for exactly the reason demonstrated in the example in my last comment.  Attacking me, rather than discussing the question, isn't going to help you.

Comment: @cluemein And by strawmanning, you have demonstrated why your questions have not been reopened.  You are making an attempt to apply the feedback, but you seem to be of the attitude, "I have put in my effort, that makes the question acceptable."  Never mind that while, yes, effort is a good thing, it does not automatically make what you are asking acceptable.  You've been given more feedback on what you need to improve to make the question better.  You can either accept it, or not.

Comment: I have been polite, but now, I really am STARTING (caps for emphasis, so I am CLEAR on what I mean) to not care at this point.

Comment: @cluemein And yet there have been quite a lot of people who have looked at your question, and quite a lot more have felt that it was too broad than felt that it wasn't.  It seems that your opinion of how broad a question should be simply differs from the other members of the community.  SO is designed for *specific* programming questions.

Comment: @cluemein If you don't care then that's certainly your decision.  Asking quality questions that meet SO's guidelines is hard.  If you can't/won't meet them, then that's your decision to make.  There are plenty of people who have no interest in asking questions SO considers acceptable, and that's fine.

Comment: @cluemein Again, *you are using the answer to prop up your question*.  Questions have to stand on their own in order to be valid.  Whether you got an answer or not is entirely immaterial.  From a quick read of your first question, it seems to be asking more for a primer on testing than an actual problem.  I don't use SO much, but if I did, for something like this, I would attempt to solve the problem on my own, and if I ran into a problem, I would narrow it to the specific issue I'm having.  The second seems to be a best practice question.  Doesn't seem to be a programming issue.

Comment: And I'm done.  There's no reasoning with you, I see.