# How can I improve my self-answered question about a task involving the use of regex?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

(I'm asking specifically for advice on the linked question, so this isn't a duplicate of [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258432) because that answers the question more generally.

I've read the similar questions to this meta-question. The general advice seems to be to make the question more specific, regardless of any answers given, but I can't see how to apply that **in this case**.)

I submitted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546079/regular-expression-backwards-search) as a Q&A on Stack Overflow because it took me some time to come up with the answer and I thought it might be useful to others. The question itself is quite brief, which I assume is the reason that it was closed as 'too broad'. But I fail to see how the question could have been made more specific without pre-empting the answer, or restricting the usefulness of the answer unnecessarily.

**Can someone please tell me what else I should have included in the question to bring it up to the standard expected here at SO?** (In case of doubt, the answer will show exactly what information was being sought, but obviously the question cannot include the answer or it would not be a question!)

For non-10K-ers:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I agree it is too broad, accepted answer or no accepted answer. What if there was another answer added that gave you an entirely different approach? And a third? And then someone rehashes one of the approaches with another twist. And more. And more. *Too broad* does not mean unanswerable. It means there are too many possible answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what if the question would have an example text and an initial non-working regex?

Comment: @rene: perhaps; it would at least narrow down the scope to 'help me fix my approach to the problem' rather than 'give me any approach to this problem'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wanted the an answer that would work with *any* RegEx, so giving a specific one in the question would have negated the point of the question entirely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the possibility of other answers makes a question inadmissible for SO then no Perl question would ever be accepted, because, you know, TMTOWTDI. Ok, tongue slightly in cheek there, but I'm sure you don't really mean that.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: @IanGoldby: Even the Perl syntax is limited enough that the number of viable answers is limited. Your *class* of questions is not. I know that you created a self-answer, but your question still needs to be able to pass the quality standards for the site *on its own*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand the question has to stand alone. What I'm looking for here is suggestions to make the question meet SO's quality standards, without making it so specific that readers will think the answer I provided doesn't apply to their own circumstances?

Comment: Your title is misleading, that question doesn't have an accepted answer. (It might have an _acceptable_ answer but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @Matt Not sure what happened there. I did accept the answer. Perhaps it lost the accepted flag when the question was deleted. (Perhaps this is something that happens with self-answered questions to make them easier to delete.)

Comment: @IanGoldby: plenty of good answers address the specific problem, then explain the generic solution to the problem in broader terms. Don't worry about making your question specific here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the advice. I suppose I was trying to create a kind of canonical Q&A. Maybe I'll resubmit it sometime with a very specific question. Kind of hard to invent a very specific question once you've got the general answer. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @IanGoldby: take a look at [this canonical q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response); the Python chat room created that one to address a very common Python beginners question. The question is specific, but the answer covers all the bases.

Comment: Not a dupe at all.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of 'too broad' includes 'write this code for me'. That's essentially what this question is: write this regex for me. As such, i also would have closed it as too broad.

Comment: Does that mean that carrying this information (specifically the answer) is detrimental to the goals of SO? _Yes, I know it was the question that was closed not the answer, but you can't post an answer without a question._

Comment: I can't see the answer, but it sounds like it provided a good solution.  As you said, it's the question that was closed - not the answer. If the question had been "this regex isn't working", it might have been more on topic, and it would be a good answer.

Comment: I think the bunch of "this regex isn't working" questions on SO are mostly useless and even duplicated, and I'd love to burn most of them to smithereens. On the contrary, OP's question is interesting, but it is hard to ask, since it is on the level of a "task with regex" instead of specific input or output.