# What to do with on-hold questions which gave the asker not even the slightest hint about what was wrong with their question?

Tags: support, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

When a custom close reason is used to put a question on-hold, a *very* undescriptive, unhelpful close reason is put in the yellow box under the question:

> **put on hold** as off-topic by [list of closers] 4 mins ago
>
> - This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), please edit the question.

And that's fine.  There's not much else that can be done for the automated reason posted here when a custom close reason is used.

And the custom close reason used *is* posted as an auto-comment.  And anyone who uses this close reason increments the comment's upvote count.

But what do we do when the close reason isn't even remotely helpful?  When the close reason doesn't even indicate what specific part of the help center the question might violate?

[image]

Now the question is put on hold with the ultimately unhelpful automatically generated yellow-box (except perhaps the edit link).  And there's not a single comment under the question to indicate how the question can be improved, or what specific aspect of it makes it off-topic (hint: being on-topic elsewhere doesn't make a question off-topic at the source site).

I don't expect there's any sort of feature request to solve this.  I understand automated systems have their limits.

But what should I do as a user who sees this?

Comment: Wouldn't there be a comment like "*This question would be better suited for CR.SE that for SO*"? Or does that comment get deleted when the question gets closed?

Comment: Yes there would.  That doesn't explain why the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow though.  Being on-topic on one Stack Exchange site doesn't make a question off-topic on all other Stack Exchange sites.  There is overlap.

Comment: I'd tell any asker who sees this that it's their prerogative to **go to the help center** and familiarize themself with what is and isn't on-topic -- it's pretty well organized over there, they should be able to figure it out. The custom close reason comments should, if used right, give enough of an idea as to what to consider. It's not the community's job to give a detailed instruction list of what to do to make an on-hold question on-topic.

Comment: @sphanley This question is effectively about when the custom close reason doesn't do what your comment (rightfully) says it should be doing.  I'm asking about what to do about this scenario not as the asker, but as an observer (particularly when I don't see any evidence the question should even be closed anyway).

Comment: If you don't think it should be closed, vote to reopen? I guess I just don't see any alternative to this - if the custom closers aren't clear, and it isn't apparent, what else is there that anyone possibly **could** do?

Answer (score 15):

If you agree that the question is off-topic and believe you are able to articulate the reason better, you can leave a comment to that effect.

If you disagree and don't see any reason at all that the question should be closed, you can vote to reopen. IMO, it's preferable that a question stays open if nobody is able to explain why it's expressly off-topic, mostly so that it can be answered if it's indeed answerable on-site, and because you can sometimes assume the asker posted on the site they did for a good reason. Innocent until proven guilty, and so on.

If you are unsure... you could post here to get some more eyes on the question, although of course you'll probably invoke the meta effect by doing so. Unfortunately, I'm not sure anything else can be done outside of meta.

Comment: Also, if you disagree and it's not closed yet, comment, and, if you have time and ability, answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell actually editing is probably more productive as you "fix" the question

Answer (score -13):

There is a systemic problem on Stack Exchange sites (and other wiki sites like Wikipedia) where busybodies close and otherwise block questions they view to be less-than-perfect. This is destructive behavior I have to assume is caused by perverse motivations in the system.

Users voting to close questions or put questions on hold almost never bother to write a comment about why they're taking that action. My guess it that most often their reasoning is rushed and rather arbitrary.

**Closing questions and putting questions on hold should be taken seriously rather than being done casually.**

Comment: *"i have to assume is caused by perverse motivations in the system"* Yes, to clean up the overflow of crap. Do you have a better idea of how to stem the tide? *"Users voting to close questions or put questions on hold almost never bother to write a comment about why they're taking that action."* Yes, they always do. They select a closure reason from one of the canned list of reasons, which has a built-in comment, or they must type their own. *"There is a systemic problem in Stack Exchange sites (and other wiki sites like wikipedia)..."* Perhaps the "problem" is that we have quality standards?

Comment: What tide needs be stemmed? What is the problem with having even 10% of questions be of low quality temporarily? Very often questions are bombarded with disapproval instead of being given advice toward improvement. Wikipedia's advice of don't bite the newbies is widely ignored here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Please_do_not_bite_the_newcomers . Also choosing a canned reason is NOT a comment, and is rarely helpful toward improving a question because it doesn't have context. The "standards" you speak of are nonexistent and in this case refer to simple user biases.

Comment: [Thought experiment: What would happen if we didn't have close votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286407/839601)

Comment: The tide of horrible questions. I don't know what site you're looking at, but there are a lot more than 10% of questions that are low-quality. More to the point, questions are put on hold in order to provide advice. You might say that we could do better in providing that advice to people whose questions are put on hold, but that's it's purpose. You don't want to leave an unclear or problematic question open and let it attract answers while you're simultaneously trying to get the question cleaned up. Because then, once the question's problems get fixed, you have a bunch of invalidated answers.

Comment: The "standards" are quite clear, discussed in detail in the site help as well as on Meta. There is a broad consensus among the community about which types of questions are acceptable and unacceptable. Meta is the place we quibble over differences, so if you hang around here long enough, you'll see plenty of disagreement. But in general, the policies are quite clear and easy to understand. Yes, perhaps they are "biases", but they're widely held biases, developed over time and with experience. All standards are really biases. Not sure what that matters.

Comment: As far as "biting newbies", there is no biting going on here. If you see rudeness, that's also against our policies, and it should be flagged. But holding people to the guidelines is not biting. It's the way any civil, moderated venue is run. Just because it's your first time to a particular host's house doesn't mean you can trash the place. No one gets a free pass. Not even users who have been around forever and amassed lots of reputation. Their questions aren't immune to closure.

Comment: According to the information in the link gnat gave, less than 10% of questions are closed. I agree that bad questions should be given advice, but my issue is that most of the time advice is NOT given.

Comment: I have 11,000 points on SO and busy bodies have sometimes commented that I should "know better". Clearly the policies are not clear and are not easy to understand. Not only that, the ones that are easy to understand are not easy to agree with.

Comment: There is widespread rudeness, if you defined rudeness as voting for closure without comment. Holding users to guidelines without attempting to guide them IS certainly biting. It is nowhere near my first time on Stack Exchange sites and I am constantly bitten by moderators. I don't give a shit how consistent moderators are in biting people who are new or old, biting people without being helpful is wrong and harmful to SE sites. Consistency in harmful behavior is not a badge of honor.

Comment: @BT `There is widespread rudeness, if you defined rudeness as voting for closure without comment.`  But that's an *absurd* definition of rudeness.  It's in no way a rude act.  There are simply too many people posting too many bad questions to hold every single one of their hands as while they ignore everything that they're being told because they don't care at all about the site, its rules, or its users, and just want someone to give them some code.  The people constantly posting inappropriate questions are the ones being rude; we're simply indicating that such behavior isn't welcome here.

Comment: @Servy The things deemed inappropriate are far too broad, and it IS rude to treat everyone as if they don't care about this site without attempting to see if they respond appropriately. Beyond rude, its incredibly damaging to this community. Saying there are "too many people posting" bad questions is a cop out - if we don't have enough people moderating, then we just can't moderate everything. Lowering the quality of moderating in an attempt to churn more quantity is absurdly short sighted.

Comment: @BT That's like telling a teacher they're not allowed to fail a student if they're not spending at least an hour of 1-1 time tutoring them outside of class.  It's a completely absurd notion.  It's entirely impossible, so demanding it is a non-starter, and fundamentally *it's not their responsibility*.  In just the same way, we are not required to spend an enormous amount of time holding the hands of the people violating the site's rules and standard in order to inform them that they're violating the standards. That you're sitting there telling me you want more bad content is just dumbfounding.

Comment: That is not at ALL what i'm saying. Your analogy is awful and absurd if I might borrow your word. Its more like tearing up a student's paper without giving them feedback and expecting them to turn in a better one very soon. It IS a teacher's responsibility to give students feedback, just as it is the responsibility of moderators to give feedback on questions they think are bad quality. I'm dumbfounded that you're misunderstanding the situation so fundamentally.

Comment: @BT First off, you've been using the site for 6 years and you still don't know what a moderator is, or realize that people downvoting or voting to close a question virtually never are moderators?  Second, no, it's *not* their responsibility to hold every single user's hand every time they violate the rules.  It's the *user's* responsibility to read and follow the rules.  If someone decides to help them out and assist them, that's all well and good, but nobody is *obligated* to do so.

Comment: You claim that I'm misunderstanding the situation when you clearly have no experience whatsoever with the site's rules, guidelines, and expectations of users.  You can't just make up your own rules, demand that everyone else use them, and claim that they're misunderstanding the situation for not abiding by your own expectations that conflict with the community's actual rules and standards.  (Oh, and how have you still not learned to @ reply when replying to someone's comment?  Are you just using someone else's account, because you're acting like someone who's never used the site before.)

Comment: @Servy  Honestly, you're incredibly rude, I'm not gonna continue talking to you. Take your hostility elsewhere. You're clearly the type of harmful user i'm talking about.

Comment: And for the record, I've been using the site for 6 years without knowing how to tell the difference between mods and regular users because I'm on here to ask and answer questions, providing positive value to the users of this site. I'm not using Stack Exchange to delve into administrative details or to censor people - believe it or not.