# Reevaluating Software Recommendation Questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, recommendation-questions

The [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is now up for a while and proves that questions for which software will fit which purpose questions can be great content.

I think we should take that as evidence that

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow [...]

should be reevaluated. At least the "Software library" part of that close reason is not attracting low quality content.

Of course such questions and answers need to adhere to the strict rules SR.SE has established for them ([questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/94)).

SR.SE has and will have the problem that a lot of domain experts from around the SE Network will not hang out there and have a look at their relevant tags (for reasons I don't understand, this is just an observation).

So while questions on SR.SE get answered, my overall impression is that we are missing out on lots of knowledge that is available on the relevant SE sites and that of course includes Stack Overflow.

I propose that we allow recommendation questions on Stack Overflow that handle libraries and programs that are used by developers.

Comment: One of the main reasons against allowing this on SO is that recommendations age badly. Any recommendations list will be outdated sooner or later and thereby become useless. How is SR.SE (planning on) tackling this problem? They're too young to have a lot of historic evidence yet.

Comment: @deceze I just went through the recommendations I gave on SR.SE and except one I've used all the tools since many years. In fact the syntax of Java changed more often then my Software Toolshed, so I don't think thats an actual concern for most items. Just as with regular questions a new answer can be given if a better tool shows up.

Comment: The reason domain experts avoid SR is not that much of a mystery.  Why you'd consider chasing them away from SO as well however is.

Comment: "At least the "Software library" part of that close reason is not attracting low quality content." - Are you visiting the same site as me? Most recommendation questions and answers which I closevote or flag are absolutely low quality content. I don't even need to read the SR.SE rules to know that those posts don't adhere to them.

Comment: @l4mpi That doesn't happen on SR.SE (at least not to the extend it happens on SO) and I think part of that is because we have established working rules for such questions.

Comment: Then arguably SR.SE is lucky in that it has a self-selecting audience which abides by the rules. SO arguably is not in that position. Allowing SR questions would grant legitimacy to some subset of questions which are currently getting closed, which makes separating the wheat from the chaff even harder. As mentioned above, many recommendation questions on SO are pretty darn bad.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs that might be true for SR.SE but it's not for SO. Even though we have rules that explicitly disallow those questions in the help center and the tour etc, we get tons of those questions, and most are extremely low quality. Attempting to allow them with specific restrictions will just lead to an even bigger broken window effect than what is already being caused by the old recommendation questions which were not yet cleaned up.

Comment: Short answer:  No.  Longer answer:  *Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.*

Comment: (Note that despite all the devil advocacy I'm doing above I'm sympathetic to the request. But unless you can provide some clear counterpoints to all the concerns being raised I just don't think it'd work in practice.)

Comment: @LittleBobby Not sure I understand. Can you elaborate on that long answer a bit further?

Comment: @deceze - yes I can.  ***Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.***

Comment: @LittleBobby Ah, got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Angelo IMO another reason why SR.SE works and SO wouldn't is because SR.SE is smaller. I seriously have my doubts that you'd continue to receive high quality answers there once every Bob and their uncle start visiting SR.SE and throw their favourite recommendation du jour out there. A small audience arguably is a positive here.

Comment: @deceze - I was just thinking the same thing.  Software Recs is a small site that can be easily moderated; Stack Overflow is a huge, highly visible site that is harder to moderate.  Software Recs can crack down on low-quality questions fairly quickly, whereas Stack Overflow would be inundated with [crap like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901547/what-is-the-best-web-scraping-software-for-building-contact-information-database)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Answer: Noooooooooooooo. TLDR: No

Comment: Another advantage of SR.SE being small is that people looking to advertise their products aren't really incentivised to go there to do it, because the audience is so small.  The bigger it is, the more people will look to try to get their spam on it.  SO, on the other hand, is much larger, and as a result, people come here all the time to post spam to these kinds of questions.

Comment: ["you may notice that their norms on asking and answering differ a lot from those at Stack Overflow..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286986/839601) --> that's what allows recommendation questions fly well there, and that's what breaks such questions at SO. And, no, "back-porting" SR.SE norms to SO won't help, it would only make it too complicated to use ("- how do I ask and answer? - well, the rules will differ depending on whether you ask about coding or recommendations, you need to check these 4 sections in hep center to understand")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So while questions on SR.SE get answered, my overall impression is that we are missing out on lots of knowledge that is available on the relevant SE Sites and that of course includes StackOverflow.

62% of Software Rec's questions have at least one answer compared to 88% on Stack Overflow. Only 24% have an accepted answer compared to 56% on Stack Overflow.

To compare to another SE site, 77% of GIS' questions have answers and 39% have an accepted answer. To compare to another beta site, 97% of The Great Outdoors' questions have at least one answer and 67% have an accepted answer. While that seems like it would be an outlier, I checked two other betas and they also have high percentages of their questions answered.

I don't say this to rag on Software Recommendations. I think it's impressive that they've found a way to do recommendation questions in a way that fits a Q&A format. I've asked a question over there myself. But I don't agree that not allowing rec questions means missing out on a lot of knowledge. A lot of their questions end up being unanswerable because 1) it's almost impossible to prove that something doesn't exist and 2) everyone wants something for free.

> SR.SE has and will have the problem that a lot of domain experts from around the SE Network will not hang out there

That's actually an argument *against* making recs on topic.

Comment: How is it against? Should i ask and answer Visual Studio configuration questions here or on a general software usage site like superuser.com?