# Stack Overflow questions of type 'can you recommend' are closed too often

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

By pursuing the policy of closing questions with...

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

..is Stack Overflow missing valuable traffic and future loyal users?

IMHO, many of those questions are by folks who are starting out in their coding career and they genuinely want to know the answer. We slam the door shut in their face. Hardly likely to engender loyalty or future good will.

Users naturally churn. Stack Overflow's monetization by banner ads and job ads will suffer in the future if the audience is not replenished. Sure, Stack Overflow is the majority of first-page hits on many code-related searches, but that just makes people takers and not contributors. Stack Overflow should be trying to broaden the user base and encourage users to visit on a regular basis - not just when they have a problem.

The plethora of new tech (I sometimes read a question in the JavaScript topic stream and don't recognise a single library name - or is that just me?) needs some of those 'what is the best library for ...' questions just like some of their ancestors from 10 years ago in the C++ and C# topics.

What would I change? I would spend more time deciding on the merit of the question and whether it can be made more valid with editing. I would hope to see more edits heading off closes.

Comment: We're not closing the questions because we doubt that the people asking them want to know the answer, so saying that they want to know the answer isn't really relevant.  The questions are closed because they create bad content.  That people like asking quesitons that create bad content (which I wouldn't dispute) doesn't change the fact that it's bad content.  Changing the site rules to encourage more bad content instead of encouraging good content will get you more users *that contribute bad content*.  It'll *lose* you users that are here to contribute *good* content.

Comment: *is SO missing valuable traffic and future loyal users* At thousands of questions asked per day, I think not. Also, [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Stack was created to NOT be a popularity contest in answers, between 17 different tools/libraries that all do the same thing. All the answers on these will be opinions, or low-value answer. We may be missing on some traffic.... but AFAIK, we've never been about quantity, so it isn't an issue.

Comment: If you want to ask an you recommend questions we have sites for that: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Most of poorly specified what's the best... would be off-topic on those even so.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan and even then we have to ["make sure that questions and answers are popular for the right reasons"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: @Braiam I think that comment was for Patrice, since he mentioned popularity? I was just saying that we've got plenty of rope with which to hang ourselves ;).

Comment: There's also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297244/reevaluating-software-recommendation-questions and closely related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294130/allow-software-tool-recommendations-for-niche-purposes. I think most of these questions end up deleted but I don't see any new arguments here.

Comment: *I would hope to see more edits heading off closes.* That would be great except the only way for that to happen is for the OP to fix it. Most rec/find requests are just a very brief description of what they want to do. Any attempt to change it into a "how to" by anyone else would make it too broad. The vast majority are unsalvageable by anyone other than the OP and 99% of the time they flat out refuse to do so.

Comment: related: [Thought experiment: What would happen if we didn't have close votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286407/839601)

Comment: Will the vanquishing never cease?

Comment: @gnat Nice link thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> IMHO many of those questions are by folks who are starting out in their coding career and they genuinely want to know the answer. We slam the door shut in their face. Hardly likely to engender loyalty or future good will.

If the user is just starting out, Stack Overflow is just not the right place to visit. There are hundreds of places on the internet to learn about programming. But Stack Overflow is trying to be something different; It is trying to be a high-quality Q/A site for specific programming questions, and it must set rules and have standards to maintain this quality.

Because of these standards and rules, some questions are going to be turned down, closed, and deleted. And that is OK. Certain questions just do not work well in a Q&A format, and that is something we all have to accept if we want to contribute here.

> Users naturally churn. SO's monetization by banner ads and job ads will suffer in the future if the audience is not replenished. Sure, SO is the majority of first-page hits on many code-related searches, but that just makes people takers and not contributors. SO should be trying to broaden the user base and encourage users to visit on a regular basis - not just when they have a problem.

True, we'd all want more contributors, but we also want to have *good* contributors. We'd love to have more contributors, but if those contributors are hurting the site's quality, they are part of the problem.

Part of being a good contributor is following the rules of the community you participate in. If you don't want to, then you simply should not participate.

But also think about the flip side of this. What happens if we do allow any kind of content to be posted here? Sure we will please some users, but what about the users that actually contribute *good* content? We'll be driving away many good users because of allowing low-quality posts.

Stack Overflow cannot sacrifice quality of users, over quantity of users. Otherwise, we'd be like any other programming forum. Allowing anything and everything, regardless of whether it is detrimental to the site's quality.

> The plethora of new tech (I sometimes read a question in the JavaScript topic stream and don't recognise a single library name - or is that just me?) needs some of those 'what is the best library for ...' questions just like some of their ancestors from 10 years ago in the C++ and C# topics.

I understand that, but recommendation questions just don't work well here. These types of questions attract things such as spam, outright bad answers, and many different opinions. In short, they attract bad content.

> What would I change? I would spend more time deciding on the merit of the question and whether it can be made more valid with editing. I would hope to see more edits heading off closes.

If the question is simply off-topic, no amount of editing will change that. For an edit to be able to salvage such a question, one would most likely need to completely change the topic. And by then, the question is better of closed as that is not what the OP intended.

I understand where you are coming from, and it would be great if we could have more contributors and have more traffic. But if those changes bring about bad, low-quality content, there only making it harder on us. And the content they leave must be closed and/or deleted.

The entire reason that Stack Overflow is so popular, is because people know they can find high-quality Q&A sessions without scrolling through long threads of useless posts.

As @Braiam has already said, we want to be popular for the right reasons. But if we have to become a little less popular, or lose a little traffic for trying to maintain good quality, then so be it.

Comment: Thanks Leaf for taking the time to write a clear and detailed answer.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Glad to help!

Answer (score 16):

We want to ["make sure that questions and answers are popular for the right reasons"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/), and the right reason is a library of high quality community curated answers. We do not need more traffic as we are near the top (SO is in the [top 194 in the US according to Quancast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=US), [Alexa put us at 44 in the global rank](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com)).

We are so high in the top, that we have virtually no competitors in the business of Programming Q&A, and that kind of forces us to reject some kind of content... because nobody can watch a flood of crap storming in and would like to participate on such site. Stack Overflow is as famous as it can be, and it should be famous for the right reasons.