# Should we do something about users answering closed questions in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions

I often see questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859671/outdoor-programming-activities) where, despite being closed for being off topic, it gets answers in the comments section. It's almost always a recommendation question.

Should I be flagging comments like these? Closing questions doesn't discourage people from requesting recommendations if they get answers anyway but I don't want to waste moderator's time if this isn't considered a big deal.

---

To clarify since both answers mention it: I'm not against people using comments to help the user make an off topic question on topic. It's my understanding that this is something the community wants to happen and I've also left comments like this. My question above is only about off topic questions getting answered in comments after they were closed.

Comment: They'll just disappear if/when the question disappears.

Comment: That example is a painfully off-topic question.  On another note, that kind of post is likely to get Roomba-ed or deleted outright.  That doesn't handle the "discourge people" part though.

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: This was even more off-topic than boat programming.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yeah, it's usually not a big deal. You don't get very much editing freedom with comments anyway, so the best someone could do is hint towards potential solutions or point the user to an external link or something, which doesn't really harm anybody as comments don't grant rep either. If helpful comments — be it comments on how to improve the question, or comments that address the subject matter — can prevent the OP from flipping out just because their question got closed, even better.

If the question is blatantly off-topic then it's probably better for the question to disappear altogether, either on its own or through delete votes. Eventually, it will. As you currently do not have enough reputation to cast delete votes, there is nothing else you need to do (though you can always comment or vote as you deem fit).

If a heated discussion *does* ensue in the comments while the question is still alive, that's when someone should step in, either to settle the dispute, or to expeditiously delete the question altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be sure that not flagging was the correct thing to do.

Comment: Sometimes I hint at, or plainly *give*, a link to a website if the question is only to be closed because of the strictly enforced "no recommendations" rule. With which I happen to agree so the same question gets a close vote as well. Call me duplicious. (The linked question is totally *not* a good example for my routine!)

Comment: _"which doesn't really harm anybody as comments don't grant rep either"_ There is more to life than rep. The harm being done here is in encouraging the OP to post yet more off-topic dren. It worked for them this time, right?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: True. The harm would have already been done though and trying to remove the comments individually would be a waste of time and resources - might as well remove the question altogether. Closing a question doesn't prevent anyone > 50 rep from commenting, but deleting it does. And, eventually, the user will be subject to rate limits. Again, the comments themselves aren't a terribly big deal - the root of the problem is in posting off-topic questions, and the system already has safeguards against that.

Comment: @BoltClock: I propose that the _real_ root of the problem is that the OP thought it would be worthwhile to post off-topic questions in the first place. That an off-topic question was posted was a direct result of that. (And they thought it worthwhile probably mainly through ignorance but, often, there is a shade of "yeah I know it's off-topic, but I just want help, and I figured I'd get it here"). But, yeah, the damage has already been done. I guess I'd prefer to discourage such comments being written in future.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what you say suggests that "helpful" comments should be [downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/165773) :)

Comment: @gnat: Almost! I am more interested in what is helpful for the wider site and community than for a single OP (optimising for individuals doesn't scale), so going by that definition you are wrong. But going by "helpful for the OP"? Yes, I suppose so. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit going by definition of what is helpful for site and community, I put quote signs around that word, to indicate that it ain't necessarily truly helpful. As for "helpful for the OP", I honestly don't care much about this, since askers are at the very bottom of SE food chain, ["Askers -> feed answerers -> feed voters -> feed googlers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes/286986#comment160057_286986)

Comment: @gnat: Damn straight :)

Answer (score 11):

I frequently leave a comment on a question that I've flagged or voted to close to help direct the user, and if I can offer any guidance I try to ("you sound like you're looking for something like ....").  The fact that SO doesn't exist to give recommendations (and that recommendation questions aren't good material for perpetuity on SO) doesn't mean we can't offer recommendations sometimes (or answer part of a really broad or opinion based question).

My goal is generally to help the user come up with a question that would be suitable to ask, whether because it shows more research effort or is specific enough to a particular problem.  I figure they'll see the comment, perhaps do a little more searching or clarifying, and either edit the question or ask a better one.  And the fact that the question is close-able doesn't mean that we all have to pretend like it's impossible to help the user who asked it.  Or maybe the comment will be enough to help them resolve the issue and move on.

Or maybe they won't get it anyway because the question really was poorly posed and we all just move on with our lives.

Comment: _"Or maybe the comment will be enough to help them resolve the issue and move on."_ Then next time, they'll do it all over again since you have taught them that posting off-topic questions works for them here. Great.

Comment: I dunno, if I posted an off topic question and it got closed I'd probably avoid the hassle.  Or at least try to think about how to ask a better question next time.  I don't think it has to be so adversarial though, the main problem with OT questions are that they shouldn't remain on the site

Comment: Unfortunately most SO noobs don't think like that :) So it's not adversarial: it's self-preservation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As a comment to your first comment: I don't think that OT askers have such a Manichean behavior. The whole SO experience is a matters of _positive/negative reinforcement_ system for all participants. By getting their question answered (through comment or not), the OPs definitively get an immediate reward for their behavior. But having their question closed, downvoted, badly commented or possibly deleted, not mentioning the system eventually forcing them to register a new account to post more questions, are all negative feedback signals.There is nothing like a free lunch…

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit do you have some hard numbers that this happens, and how often this happens?  I'm not fully convinced that this happens that much.

Comment: @eis: Purely anecdotal.

Comment: @eis You can't really measure objectively cases where the OP knowingly posts an off topic question because they expect it to be answered in comments, even if it gets closed.  People will, on occasion, admit that they knew it was off topic and just don't care, but most won't actually tell you that, so there's no way of differentiating the cases of people who knowingly post an offtopic question from those who honestly thought the question was on topic.  So we know it does happen, but we have no way of measuring how much it happens.

Comment: @Servy true, but what can be measured is the tendency of people repeating the behaviour after doing it once. It would be interesting to see some numbers on if people do this again after experiencing one case of closure + answer in comments.

Comment: @eis How do you write some automated tool to determine if there is an answer in comments?

Comment: It'd probably be enough to write a tool to check how often users post questions that get closed repeatedly (but not enough to get their account suspended for it), and then get the comments from those questions that either have a length over a certain minimum (i.e. long enough to be an 'answer') or a link to an external site (i.e. not a 'this is a duplicate of' link).

Answer (score -1):

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821820/non-blocking-communications-in-mpi-order-of-messages) today, which was closed as too broad with one of the voters stating in the comments that

> this question seems quite theoretic and should at least be accompanied by a clear example, preferably with code. Why don't you try something like philosophy,stackexchange.com?

In the context of MPI (which the question was tagged with) this is certainly not true and both questions have a clear (and straight-forward) answer. I don't have the right to cast reopen votes yet and thus a comment was the only way of answering the question. Since I was a bit desperate and wanted to do all I could for the user to see the answer before the question vanishes, I even flagged the question (predictably, the flag was declined).

Obviously, in such a vast, self-moderated community mistakes will be made and questions that should arguably stay open get closed really fast; a comment is then the only way to at least hint at the answer before the question eventually vanishes.