# Reply to downvoter(s)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, downvotes, comment-replies

[There is an interesting discussion about the effects of close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes/286780#286780) - though it will be interesting to have non-closed votes I don't think is possible.
But at least I would like to have an option to request an explanation on a downvote. It is not pleasant to get such a thing when you think you have posted a good answer. Probably a simple reply will be enough - and if somebody wishes to explain his/her motives - much better.

Something like:

> @downvoter - why are you doing this to me?

and if there's downvoter(s), they will receive the reply.

Comment: Potential problem. User posts terrible question, gets 25 downvotes, and now he can ping *every single one of them*. With the amount of downvotes many of us cast, do you really want that many notifications?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​There's nothing stopping me from explaining my downvotes if I wish to do so. If I haven't, then you can safely assume that _I don't want to_. This may be because I feel others have already sufficiently explained why the post is downvote worthy. Or it could be because I don't really have anything polite to say. In any case, all your inbox notification will achieve is annoy me. Why would you want that?

Comment: Usually, I will either post a comment explaining why the post needs to be improved if I think it can be **or** downvote if I don't think it can't be improved. Explaining downvotes is pointless, asking for users to explain their downvotes is pointless.

Comment: It's worse than pointless.  Yet again, it suggests moving the responsibility for fixing bad questions on to those who review them, instead of the moro.. askers who post them.

Comment: _@downvoter - why are you doing this to me?_ You have 17.5K rep. I feel betrayed.

Answer (score 11):

This has already been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post?lq=1), the meta for the entire network.