# How many Stack Overflow accounts are banned from asking questions?

Tags: support, post-ban, statistics

I am just curious as to how many accounts (in number or in percentage) are banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Roughly speaking...Not enough

Comment: @codeMagic That's for sure!

Comment: This information is not disclosed anywhere.  It would be a very meaningless number anyway, the number of banned accounts is far greater than the number of banned users.

Comment: We don't need to know many things, but we can find them out with tools like the Data Explorer. and these knowledges can help guide and improve community moderation.

Comment: @Oxinabox this is not exposed through SEDE.

Comment: @ Baiam: Indeed it is not. I was posting as a counter arguement to @yes4me statement that we "don't need to know".

Comment: @Braiam: Thanks for adding the 'Statistics' tag to the question. I wanted to add something of that sort but I didn't know that it existed.

Comment: @yes4me Both of those facts are quite obvious. It is not clear, however, what is so dangerous about this question that would call for shutting it down so aggressively; or, for that matter, since when non-technical questions about SO became unsuitable for meta.

Comment: @duplode In what way is this question "shut down so aggressively"?  I'm curious, I don't see anything in its history that indicates anyone was trying to "shut it down"?

Comment: @Yakk I was referring only to yes4me's comment.

Comment: @tchrist *these knowledges* in context refers to the things which we do not need to know but do, such as those exposed through the data exporer and other tools. The extra knowledge we have that we did not need helps the community to moderate.

(Knowledges, like monies, fishes, or peoples is a collection of collections I guess. I'm not certain that is the right pluralisation, it might be these knowings, hmm. (Just using knowledge would be off to me since we have some knowledge from the data explore and some knowledge from other tools (like the 10K tools)))

Comment: @Oxinabox: User *tchrist* may have referred to [*knowledge* usually being](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knowledge#Noun) an [uncountable noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#uncountable).

Comment: I've seen some very [thoughtful statistical analysis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes) of user data in Meta questions in the past. If banned account percentage was made available, someone would probably be able to draw conclusions about the likelihood of certain types of new users getting question banned, and then use this knowledge to suggest improvements to the "First Post" queue.

Comment: @yes4me do explain...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [Shog9 mentions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172773/164200), question bans are not a *fixed state*. We only log when a user hits the ban, it's entirely possible for someone to potentially be in a banned state and not realize it, or even not trigger a ban because it's fluid. But I threw together some stats on logged bans.

#### The Past 30 days

- 4316 users have hit the Question Ban
- 86 of those users were able to post a question after hitting the ban

#### All Time

- 95474 accounts have hit the ban at some point
- Of those accounts, 83k have hit the ban more than once
- About 1/3 of these (30k) have gotten out of the ban and posted another question

Comment: What does "hit the ban more than once" mean? Do you mean getting unbanned and then banned again? Or do you mean they just tried to ask a question more than once while banned?

Comment: @sag they were banned, then unbanned, then hit the ban again