# Why should I bother searching for duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm active in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and associated "web development" tags. I've noticed a surge in the number of simple, oft-asked questions getting answers from relatively high-rep users (generally over the "trusted user" privilege... 20K+).

A recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41048993/215552

This is frustrating, as the answers are already out there, written and waiting to be voted up by users who found them useful, but I'm sure there are some users who see these questions as having been answered by people with gold badges in the language, or just high rep, and won't bother with the close vote. I also think it's unfair to the people who've answered the canonical or "original" question, but hey, life's not fair, so forget them.

Not to mention, seeing as I only have accumulated 4k rep, who am I to disagree?

So, the question is, beyond the motivation to keep the site clean (which is obviously not a priority for these high-rep, trusted users, so why should it matter to me?), what incentive do I have to mark things as duplicates? Should I just start answering duplicates so that I too can ascend to the lofty heights of 20K+?

This discussion question is similar to [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/215552) except I don't want to discuss deterrents; I want to know if I should just stop searching for duplicates, since it doesn't seem to make much difference if 20k+ users are asking and answering them.

Comment: the fact someone is doing even if it's wrong isn't a free pass to do it yourself.... continue flagging/downvoting/close-voting. The rep is inconsequential. The fact they have 20K, but their post is bad... well it means "the post is bad". full stop.

Comment: Does being able to sleep at night count as a reason?

Comment: In this instance, the question asks for nested as opposed to just the top level. This is **significantly** different than the proposed duplicate. There is a lot of vitriol in this post, and for what? Especially given that your assessment that the other post answers the question is incorrect.

Comment: These users' answer lists are full of questions you can easily dupe close

Comment: @Servy - The object given in the question shows a top layer, with a nested layer that has a match for the replace, as well as another nested layer, that also has a match for the replace. That requires recursion, as can be seen in the answer posted.

Comment: @TravisJ **Significantly**? Really? I guess we have different tolerances for how we think about programming. Because I would think it doesn't take much to understand that if the value is an object, you'd need to call the same function on the value. And if you don't like that dupe, there's another one I added later. Feel free to reopen and reclose.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Many people struggle with recursion, in both identifying it and implementing it. I have seen this struggle often in questions, so yes, the difference is significant. I agree with your alternative suggestion for a duplicate.

Comment: I am surprised this has not been closed yet since it has been discussed in the past.

Comment: i mean, it is a problem we still have, one that we don't have a solution to. Worth discussing? The one thing that shows how much the network trusts you is reputation. however, it can be easily gained by doing things that don't help make this site a better place.

Comment: Answer is still "searching for duplicates is personal call. There is absolutely no initiative to close questions as duplicates."... Agree with @KevinB as there is unfortunately really not much value in discussing again until SE decides to do something about it.

Comment: I did search and didn't find anything specific...so I posted a question. Is that not what SO is for?

Comment: It is the kind of rhetorical question that occupies parents, usually through "if all your friends jump off a bridge, would you too?"  Some do get the response "heck yeah, pool party!"  You're old and wise enough to have your own party, if that's what you want.  Just keep in mind what that 20k means once you burned a lot of your free time.  Are they just Internet points or does it measure how reputable you are?  Many users don't make it, typically flame out somewhere north of 10k.  Parties don't last forever.

Comment: @HansPassant jump off a bridge - http://xkcd.com/1170/ :)

Comment: The only reason to look at a user's rep is to determine whether a link to the help center is warranted.

Comment: There is a selfish motive, too. Finding a duplicate is often significantly easier than writing a good answer of your own. Why do extra work if someone else has already done it? Literally the only argument against searching for duplicates is ME NO GET REPZ, which is...well, if you want to be *that guy*, we can't stop you.

Comment: @CodyGray For simple questions it's often *easier* to just post an answer than to search for a duplicate with a good answer, particularly with how many times the duplicate question will get low quality answers instead of being closed as a duplicate with a good answer.  Finding the one good duplicate in a sea of duplicates with low quality answers will often take more time than posting your own answer.  Obviously there are exceptions, or cases where you remember the exact title of a quality duplicate, but for many users that won't be the case.

Comment: @Servy Actually, most of the time (as was the case with the example) I just copy and paste the title into Google (sometimes with the site: syntax) and look at the first few hits and find a dupe. Doesn't take that long, and you can get 90%-100% of the way toward an answer using those hits.

Comment: @chovy SO should always be the last resort (as indicated in the [ask] page I linked to). It appears as though you did a quick search and didn't find anything that was exactly the same as your problem. So, rather than making an attempt to solve the problem yourself, you just wrote up a work request for SO. Luckily there's plenty of people on SO that love to do other people's work for them, so now you have an answer. Congratulations.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Like I said, for many types of questions its easy enough to provide duplicates, but when there are way more duplicates with low quality answers by people who never found a duplicate with a good answer to close, wading through all of them is often more work than writing up an answer.  It will of course vary based on the topic, but there are certainly lots of cases where finding the duplicate is more work.

Comment: @CodyGray that selfish motive is well balanced with nice comments from OP in a spirit of "why the **** you close my precious question as duplicate - it is clearly not you moron and can't *** read..." - not everyone can handle such comments calmly. Unfortunately there is no harm in not searching for duplicate and either answering or just skipping (as someone else will definitely answer - so OP happier than getting post closed as duplicate)... What's good for site just does not give any rewards for desired behavior.

Comment: You'd think 20k points on SO profile would indicate I knew how to use SO but apparently not.

Comment: @chovy with a 122K of rep and 8 years with 2K+ close votes I must not know either.

Comment: @epascarello: I'm a moderator. Which idiots elected me?

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Because I would think it doesn't take much to understand that if the value is an object, you'd need to call the same function on the value." I agree with you, but I've noticed a **very** established pattern whereby **tons** of inexperienced or... less-competent programmers just can't seem to get their heads around the idea of "to deal with something that's nested, apply the same technique at each level of the nested structure". There are tons of questions on the site that relate to more basic questions like this. Stuff like "how do I pull *this* thing out of my JSON?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well... What's your goal?

I've seen folks on some forums answer the same question every day for years.

I've seen folks answer the same question until they couldn't bear to answer it anymore.

I've seen folks throw up their hands and post "search, damn you!" in response to every new instance of some common question, and I've seen forums where the first page of posts was entirely pinned topics, the "canonical" list of frequently-asked questions. And of course, they were *still* asked every day.

I'm sure you've seen these things too. And from these arises the utility of duplicate closure.

When we started out here, "Exact Duplicate" worked pretty much the same as every other close reason. There was no prompt for a link, nor a means of displaying them; if you knew the question had been asked previously, you closed it - same as if you knew the question was off-topic. Sometimes folks answered the question with a link to a previous one prior to closing, sometimes they'd drop a link into a comment, or edit it into the question itself, or... do nothing. The system we have grew up out of an ad-hoc process that folks who were closing questions developed; a sort of bookkeeping to forestall arguments over whether questions were being closed appropriately.

In the past 30 days, 4% of all questions asked were closed as duplicates, comprising roughly 40% of all questions closed ([10K stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last30days)). That's almost certainly lower than it should be, but still represents a significant increase from just a couple of years ago (when only about 2% of questions were closed as duplicates); most of this increase can be attributed to two major changes:

1. Askers can trigger the closure of their own questions by confirming that a proposed duplicate is accurate.
2. Tag-badge holders can instantly close any question in their tag as a duplicate.

Critically, neither of these changes does anything to directly encourage folks to *find* duplicates (rather than just answering). But, as I hinted above, most of the motivation there is intrinsic anyway. Two years ago, 4% of questions had duplicates suggested; today, that's 6% - it would appear that the growth in duplicates closed matches the growth in duplicates found, which in turn spiked as soon as we made bothering to find them *more effective*.

So back to your question...

#### Why find duplicates?

Might as well ask, "why answer questions" or "why write blog posts" or "why write documentation" or heck, "why write a novel". Many people *are* moved to do these things, and many people benefit from their work... But that doesn't mean *you* should. We certainly have enough novels.

Reputation is meaningless, [an entertaining game](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230709/place-answers-into-demilitarized-zone-instead-of-5-minute-grace-period/230715#230715) to play while you're here but not particularly valuable, particularly once you've turned your attention elsewhere. If you wouldn't answer without reputation, then chances are your answer isn't going to be worth much with it; OTOH, if you enjoy writing answers but are sick of writing *that* answer, being able to mark new questions as duplicates of old ones relieves a certain tedium for certain *particularly driven* people.

But maybe not you. If not you, then do something else.

#### Related:

- [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes/316682#316682)
- [Thought experiment: What would happen if we didn't have close votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286407/thought-experiment-what-would-happen-if-we-didnt-have-close-votes)
- [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)
- [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212)
- [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation)
- [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, because it's a great answer and provides data to back up the contention that "it's not *that* bad". However, the advice at the end seems to be "do what you want", which blesses the behavior of people who don't search before asking a question. Your answers in those other questions are more nuanced. I especially like [the one on Thought Experiments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286780/215552), where you note that Stack Overflow exists on a shared goal. My problem is it seems that goal is less widely shared. But I'm old and people are on my lawn, so...

Comment: You can't *make* anyone share your goals; heck, you can't really even make *yourself* share anyone else's goals. Marking duplicates is important to the greater community, just like picking up litter is important to the well-being of whatever community you physically belong to... But you gotta want to help out. Here in Colorado, we make prison inmates pick up litter, and the roads are still a mess.

Comment: Interestingly, the 10K stats link shows a page that is not linked neither in the [10K privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) nor in the [Moderation Tools page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools). Is it a hidden gem?

Comment: Now I found it! It just appears in the "close" tab. [Let's add the link to “question close stats” in all the sections of the “/tools” page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288080/209901)

Comment: Arbitrarily timed update: we're currently at 20% close percentage, of which 30% duplicates (6% marked duplicate overall). While I personally think nowhere near enough questions are getting closed, questions that Need More Focus or are lacking debugging details (i.e., are lacking *problem analysis* to extract a *question* from the task) are IMO a much bigger problem than duplicates. And I'm saying that as the "omg guys please help me fix the Python canonicals so we can dupe-hammer properly, I'm begging you" guy.