# 33% of questions are ignored by community

Tags: discussion, support, questions, voting

I've noticed that a lot of my questions are ignored by community (by *ignored* I mean have no votes, no answers and only a few views) and decided to look at the situation over all questions asked by all users.

Let's look on questions that:

- were asked a week ago or earlier - I think, week is reasonable amount of time to rate or answer
- have 0 score
- have no answers

## [Here is the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1269844/are-questions-ignored)

```sql
-- PostTypeId = 1 is Question

declare @lim datetime
select @lim = max(CreationDate) from Posts
set @lim = DATEADD(week, -1, @lim)

select
  ViewCount & ~15 as ViewCountFrom,
  ViewCount & ~15 | 15 as ViewCountTo,
  count(1) as PostsCount
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and Score = 0 and AnswerCount = 0 and CreationDate > @lim
group by ViewCount & ~15
order by 1

select
  @lim as CreationDateLimit,
  'zero' as Category,
  avg(ViewCount) as AvgViewCount,
  count(1) as PostsCount
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and Score = 0 and AnswerCount = 0 and CreationDate > @lim
union all
select
  @lim as CreationDateLimit,
  'nonzero' as Category,
  avg(ViewCount) as AvgViewCount,
  count(1) as PostsCount
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and (Score <> 0 or AnswerCount <> 0) and CreationDate > @lim

select Id, ViewCount, Title
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and Score = 0 and AnswerCount = 0 and CreationDate > @lim
  and ViewCount >= 80
order by ViewCount desc
```

## Results

```
ViewCount   PostsCount
  0 -  15      9308
 16 -  31      7116
 32 -  47      1247
 48 -  63       216
 64 -  79        38
 80 -  95        12
 96 - 111         5
208 - 223         1
304 - 319         1
736 - 751         1
```

```
CreationDateLimit     Category   AvgViewCount   PostsCount
2020-07-19 05:22:07   zero       17             17945 
2020-07-19 05:22:07   nonzero    30             35884
```

## We can see

that the number of ignored questions is half of the number of others and the average number of views there is almost twice less. Almost 10K questions have less then 16 views. More then 16K questions have less then 32 views.

I believe it shouldn't be so. Of course I can't say that all questions should be answered, but at least they can be rated and viewed depending on rating.

## Examples

I'll show some of my questions as at least I can easily find them, but feel free to add some other examples.

- [Narrow inferred type when function has explicit return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63184318/4928642) - 9 views in 12 hours
- [Pass generic type argument through the literal object with different field names per each field if number of fields values is limited by 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842858/4928642) - 19 views in 20 days
- [Print updating status in multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62735084/4928642) - 16 views in 26 days
- [arguments.callee.caller, error.stack and inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62032877/4928642) - 10 views in 2 months
- [Linting based on type or usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59686855/4928642) - 18 views in 6 months
- [Remove unused enum values from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59006113/4928642) - 40 views in 8 months
- [Implement responsive overflow overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53856627/4928642) - 71 view in 1 year 7 months
- [Rest parameter with specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50979204/4928642) - 173 views in 2 years 1 month
- [iPad Safari ignores prime and double prime chars if using custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40228339/4928642) - 64 views in 3 years 9 months
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/47874179/4928642 - 95 views in 1 year, autodeleted due to inactivity
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/51851156/4928642 - 31 view in 1 year, autodeleted due to inactivity

I believe these questions were not bad. I've spent a few hours or even several days on some of them. Some questions got more that 50 views while time going, some even have comments.

## But why does nobody vote?

Votes can help to keep a question visible and make it more likely to be answered if it was not in a few hours after it was posted.

## What else can be done?

Are there some other ways to prevent skipping 33% of all questions asked?

Comment: As in all feedback systems, powered by limited resources which are competed over: it’s a power law, and I doubt there’s anything you can or the site can do about it. Lots of questions will fall into the long, lonely tail. In other words: there are many many questions and few answerers; not all can be answered, so you’re competing. So what do you want or expect? The best you personally can do is to learn what marketing tactics work best, and apply those: titles, topics, tags, time of day,  presentation, MCVE, ease of answering within a limited time window and common tools, etc.

Comment: @DanBron, I can think about a lot of different things that may try to keep good questions on top longer like amount of code and text, comments in code, time spent to write the post, rank on the site, positive status of previous questions and a lot more. But why the simplest "see good/bad question - vote" doesn't work?

Comment: Also, I’m not familiar with any of the tech mentioned, but the titles of the questions you mention aren’t exactly thrilling. Nothing in them says to me “hey, I want to check *this* out”. But maybe people familiar with the tech would read and respond to them differently; YMMV.

Comment: Because not everyone is going to click on every question. That’s what I mean by competing for limited resources - in this case, people’s time and attention. And even among those intrigued enough to open the question may not think it’s good enough or bad enough to merit a vote; most Qs I see are “meh” in my experience.

Comment: @DanBron, [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/47874179/4928642) is deleted but there is [its version in Russian](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760433/178988) rated by +3 -0 and 3 favorites (I'm not among them). I think, for some questions it's pretty easy to see that they have MCVE, description of the goal, information what exactly goes wrong and screenshot of the problem if needed. Here it got 95 views, but nobody voted.

Comment: [From this answer from Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254157): 

*"The issue is not that users like BalusC are discouraged from posting answers because answerable questions are not there, the issue is that they can't be found anymore. They are simply buried under a huge pile of help-desk questions that take excessive time to moderate and leave no valuable artifact that's worth anything to anybody other than the questioner. The "please google this for me" and "please debug my code" questions. Crowd-sourcing simple programming tasks, the volume has grown dramatically*"

Comment: @Qwertiy I can’t read Russian, but the Russian site is much smaller than the English one, right? Meaning there are relatively fewer questions competing for attention. You see this on most of the smaller stacks: they’re more accommodating of more types of Qs because they’re trying to attract an audience, and fewer Qs means more of them get individual attention. Or maybe whatever Q is about is inherently more interesting to Russians? But bottom line you can’t compare the 2 sites. Scale is the root of the issue.

Comment: Your questions are well-written. They are a bit complex which explain the low comments and engagements. But, there are plenty of experts on the respective tags who could answer them. Probably related discussion from 2014: [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756)

Comment: @adiga, answering needs time. Sometimes a lot of time. Sometimes it's just impossible to do the thing somebody asks about. But if you see the question is well formed, clear and has mcve if needed, it'l take only couple of seconds to vote.

Comment: @DanBron, I gave you a link to estimate quality of question (you have no 10K here, so can't see deleted posts), not to say that some site is better or worth. Here is a screenshot in English: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUMcD.png.

Comment: Wise words from an (now ex-) employee: ["You can't make anyone share your goals" - Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339261/why-should-i-bother-searching-for-duplicates#comment420724_339402). Now, that was about duplicate-marking, but I think it holds true for voting as well.

Comment: Would it make sense to at least encourage people to cast up/down votes in some review queues (like first posts) instead of no action needed? Because otherwise the value of your review is not much bigger than if you just clicked skip.

Comment: "One third of all questions are ignored" sounds about right to me.  That is the relative proportion of all questions asked on Stack Overflow that are either underspecified, too broad, or have some other problem with them that makes them unanswerable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, seems I forgot to filter out closed...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, same ratio for nonclosed: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1269971/are-questions-ignored. So even if you are right and the questions are mostly offtopic, they still need to be closed. Actually I don't believe all that questions are offtopic.

Comment: TBH I don't spend a lot of time curating content anymore.  It's a bit like trying to put out a house fire with a squirt gun.

Comment: @Robert, not to mention that every time I try, the feedback I get says my squirt gun is spewing gasoline.

Comment: "But why does nobody vote?" You have been member for more than five years and yet you cast less than 2300 votes total (less than 1200 on questions) In about same time frame I voted on more than 19.000 questions. I guess you are in better position to say why people don't vote. Why aren't you voting more?

Comment: If people would stop asking "my code doesn't work" questions maybe we can improve things. Unfortunately, the site is being branded as a "my code doesn't work" question kind of site. It is doomed to continue receiving them, followed by a constant decline of being useful for anything other than asking/answering.

Comment: Just a small thing: If a question hasn't been answered for some time for whatever reason it could be that the original question creator moved on. If then the question is also somewhat specific there is the risk that answering it doesn't really help many people. Why should I invest my valuable time then? Maybe 1/3 of all questions are genuinely too boring?

Comment: I think you should add tag [tag:js] to typescript questions, which has more watchers.

Comment: @TheMaster, but these questions have nothing about js - only type system there. I don't think that adding tag just to attract people is the right way.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I'm more frequent guest of ruSO (where I'm a mod by the way). If you look [my profile there](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), you'll see 13468 upvotes and 159 downvotes; 7454 on questions and 6173 on answers. And on both sites I have ratio of votes on question and answers near 50% with more votes on questions than on answers. I think it shows that I do not ignore questions, isn't it?

Comment: If one subscribes to the theory that some good questions are falling through the cracks and for some reason do not get the attention (or at least a vote) they deserve, then it would make sense to filter say a few days old questions by visits/views and look at those with low views first. It might be more beneficial than everyone staring at the same subset of questions.

Comment: Yes, I saw your profile and I can see that you are more active on ruSO. While ruSO is certainly taking some poor Q traffic away from SO, your activity there is irrelevant (besides the point that as a mod you know how to moderate) to the well being of SO. You are still asking questions here and want them to be answered, so maybe you should start voting more here, too. Please, don't take this as any kind of attack, you don't have to do anything... but my Q still stands, why aren't you voting here? Same reasons might apply to other people that are not voting.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I'm voting here too. But I vote mostly in questions that I find via google when searching for something. I'm not actively answering or browsing the site, so I don't see as much posts and vote more rare then on ruSO where I'm active enough. But when I do, I vote.

Answer (score 46):

Everything that is currently wrong with Stack Overflow comes down to two points.

1. Too many poor questions are asked.
2. Too few people are capable (have knowledge or reputation) and want to answer, vote (up or down) or close vote.

If we can magically (or in some other way) reduce the number of questions asked (and by those I mean poor questions and completely off-topic questions), there would be more eyes focusing on other questions that can be answered or at least rated.

Every user has limited amount of votes they can cast daily, be it close votes, reopen votes or rating votes - up votes or down votes.

Comment: The second point is the most important one, but especially the votes (up/down + close). Without filtering certain questions, a lot of the noise remains out there, which makes it harder for good questions to be found

Comment: But isn't one third of all question too much?

Comment: Then maybe some automation should be used to help people?

Comment: @Qwertiy I don’t know what you mean by too much. There isn’t someone with a dial in the back room labeled “% of questions to ignore”. There is no design or intent here; it’s an emergent property of the system. It can’t be “too much” or “too little” or “right” or “wrong”; it just *is*.

Comment: @Qwertiy What automation? If you draw more attention to some posts, you’re drawing it away from all the others; that’s back to square one. If you try to draw attention to *all* posts, then you’re not drawing attention to *any* of them: that’s what the situation is today; so again, square one. The issue is a mathematical one, and can’t be engineered around: there are too many questions and not enough attention. Some Qs are going to get the shaft, any way you slice it.

Comment: @Qwertiy A third is a lot, but also somewhat unavoidable.  The more popular tags (C++, C, Java, Python, Android... read: any tag with hundreds of questions per day) are bound to have a lot of questions outright drown in traffic. Niche tags might get less attention because no one really knows the answer, or the people who do are on vacation and ended up missing the question entirely. Adding automation can't fix that, nor can it fix the issues with the system itself that prevents the relatively tiny core of moderating users to stay in control of closure

Comment: @Zoe, not the stats is not about unanswered questions, it's about unrated and unanswered at the same time. You may have no an answer or have no time to answer, but it's very simple to vote if you understand the quality.

Comment: @DanBron, most part of my answers on some questions are to the questions from the main page. I rarely search for questions to answer deep. Some people watch for tags. My question was asked 12 hours ago, now it is somewhere near 70th place for [typescript] tag newest. It can be found still, but in a couple of days it'll go far enough so that nobody will enumerate so many pages. Questions are usually answered soon after publish or lost. Community user bumps some questions, but I'm not sure about questions completely without answers - usually I see questions with single answer both having 0.

Comment: @DanBron, _"If you draw more attention to some posts, you’re drawing it away from all the others; that’s back to square one."_ The idea is when some post is upvoted, it gets more attention taking it from posts that are downvoted (not by 1, of course). It's logical as we prefer to answer good questions than to answer bad questions. And in such case they both are not ignored, they are voted.

Comment: @Qwertiy re your first comment: yes, that’s what I mean by “too many questions and not enough attention”. Your Q is buried because 70 more questions piled up in the interim. Re your second: just browsing main, as you do, doesn’t sort by votes. But even if it did, you’re still back at your catch-22; your question isn’t voted on. It’s not voted on because there are too many other questions drawing limited attention from it; there are too many Qs to vote on all of them. And votes are the only way to characterize the quality of a post. The problem is the volume; I don’t know what you want.

Comment: @DanBron, main has some priorities (at least, -3 and bellow are removed). Anyway, we can say the other way: time-only sort is not the optimal way of listing the questions for answerers. Maybe shuffle questions during the month if they are on even places? Or make even lines of time-ordered questions and odd from questions with some weight to show them? That's my question is about. How we can make it better?

Comment: @Qwertiy If you have enough reputation, and you certainly have, you can always add bounty to your question to attract more attention.

Comment: @Qwertiy and I’m saying you can’t. It’s a mathematical problem, *you can’t engineer around it*. If you “apply some weight”, you are just choosing *which* 33% to ignore, you’re not reducing the 33%. And whatever weighting you choose is unfair, because SO’s whole premise is quality is judged by humans voting, and you’re trying to solve the fact that these Qs haven’t been voted on. If an algorithm could assess quality, we wouldn’t have voting. You’re saying “people are going hungry”, and I’m saying “that’s because there’s not enough pie to go around”; cutting the pie differently can’t ever help.

Comment: @DanBron, the questions are not voted because they are not viewed because there are a lot of questions and people mostly see the newest. If question is already answered it is newest still and if people will see it a bit less time, they will see some other questions from ones that were posted earlier. It's not math, people will see the questions that site will show them.

Comment: @Qwertiy I don’t know what’s confusing here. There is an inflow of N questions/day, and a voting-on-questions-rate of M/day, and M << N. If you show older questions, there are still newer questions coming in while you’re displaying the older ones, so now you’re just shifting the 33% to *those* questions, which aren’t being seen. And when *they* become older, they will obscure the questions coming in at *that* time. *Because M << N, **you can’t ever win***, you can just decide which questions you want to lose. And deciding prior to voting breaks SO’s foundational premise.

Comment: I can't say for all users, but for example I usually review exactly 1 page of the tag I'm watching. And if there's already too many answers on a question or it has very negative score - I'd usually skip it. So if that 1 page was structured in a way that it has mostly content which i'm interested in - I would on average review more questions.

Comment: @DanBron, it would be so if posting of questions would be equally distributed during the day, but it's not.

Comment: @Qwertiy However distributed throughout the day, M << N. And even if distribution mattered (it doesn’t, because M << N), reading, voting, and answering questions is also not distributed evenly: in fact, it has the same curve as asking, for the same reasons. You can’t engineer around a pie being too small!

Comment: There is a idiom we say, „there are no stupid questions, if then only stupid answers“. I am on SO since 8years and if i have time and motivation to help out and take the challenge in the question i answer or try to make sure i understood the Question. Most users come to SO because they learn and share their mistake or at least try to get help to improve. When we demotivate questioners before they get help to improve even their questions how can we expect they would reach the knowledge and reputation to give good answers in future.