# What should I do if my question has been completely ignored?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994872/how-can-i-properly-run-2-threads-at-the-same-time-that-await-things-to-happen-in) has been completely ignored. It has <20 views after 2 weeks, no downvotes, upvotes, comments, interactions whatsoever. I know I could just set up a bounty, but I was wondering why nothing happened. It has fewer views than the average uninteracted with question so, is it a *bad* question that's not too bad to be downvoted? Is there anything I can/should change about it?

So, before I bounty it, what should I edit it to be a better question for this site? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: In the Python tag, page 50 is 2 days ago so nobody will ever see your question unless they're tracking questions with recent activity. Aside from that it's just lost in the void.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I am aware this question as is will never be found, but what can I avoid for this to happen again, why did it happen and what should i do before i bounty this question to make it better

Comment: Lots of Python questions go unanswered and unvoted, it's just the nature of asking a question in such a popular tag. My advice is to provide as many relevant tags as possible and also ask an interesting question. Yes, that last suggestion is a bit tongue in cheek because now you have to figure out what's interesting to readers; this requires elevation beyond what's important to you.

Comment: As for the importance of tagging well, I have personally gained interest in regex so I will take a shot at regex questions regardless of programming language since it is nearly agnostic to the language.

Comment: See [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/289905).

Comment: Above all else, did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python before asking? If so, then explain what you tried and what didn't work. If readers feel like the question is long-winded and getting additional details will be like pulling teeth then you're just less likely to get any engagement. My napkin math tells me that Python gets 12 questions every 10 minutes so people would rather spend their energy elsewhere. Once again, nothing against your question, it's just that readers didn't find it interesting enough.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have not, I will try it thanks! If it doesn't solve it, should I edit my question and add the info, or close/delete the old one and make a new one with the extra info?

Comment: Be careful with deleting questions, there is some threshold which could get your account suspended from asking questions. Overall I recommend trying to figure out the problem yourself and update your question if you get stuck yet again. However, if you finally figure it out then you can self-answer your question. I'll try to dig up the threshold for deleting questions.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280888/should-i-delete-my-own-unanswered-questions and make an earnest effort to answer it yourself. If I see someone re-posting a question a few hours apart then they get called out for it but nobody would notice besides the automated system if you're deleting a 2-week old question.

Comment: "It has less views than the average uninteracted with questions so, is it a bad question that's not too bad to be downvoted?" Less than average is not bad. Many questions, maybe up to one half are in the same bracket. It doesn't mean that it's a bad question, just not an interesting one. With small numbers it may also just be bad luck.

Comment: I don't think it's "ignored" - you ask a more difficult question. Just the mention of threading in the title will already make everyone unqualified to just skip over it to an easier question. It's just a fact of life, some questions have a far lower target audience.

Comment: One method you can use, especially as you gain more reputation, is to add a bounty to your question if you don't get the answer(s) you are expecting, or the interaction. Just make sure, before you do bounty it, that it meets the requirements of the site again. Some off topic questions can easily be missed by users, especially in popular tags, meaning that adding a bounty to it can easily attract the *wrong* attention (downvotes) and if it truly is off-topic it may get closed by a moderator (normal users can't vote to close bountied questions, but they can custom flag them).

Comment: Be aware that your question is just not answerable at the moment. The code is incomplete, so we cannot reproduce the issue. The description is about *threads* but the code is about *processes*, so we do not actually know what you are asking about. The two actions seem to be built to wait for each other (send triggers receive), so we do not know how you want them *not* to wait for each other. Having significant fluff that requires people to actively *search* for the question does not make it any more attractive to interact with the question.

Comment: Note that [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) is setting in. Your Question is being closed now.

Comment: This question describes such a common problem that it's hard to believe it hasn't come up before on meta. However, a quick search only brought me [33% of questions are ignored by community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399936/33-of-questions-are-ignored-by-community).

Comment: Closely related: [Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265874/best-way-to-draw-attention-to-someone-elses-good-question) Duplicate on Meta SE: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)

Comment: @Trilarion Actually it's been discussed to death under subjects such as "low quality questions and new users are ruining SO".

Comment: @Trilarion See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/2191572 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/2191572 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/2191572 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/2191572 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/2191572 and notice the number of votes these posts have. I was able to pick these off page #1 if you sort by highest votes and view 50 questions per page.

Comment: @Trilarion missed on on the front page, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2191572. Reading some of the moderator resignations would be good too. You've been on Stack Overflow for over 8 years and have never seen any of these? Pity.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You may have misunderstood me. I thought that this question here is likely a duplicate. The questions you link to are great meta discussions, but not a duplicate of this particular question here, which is more about why some question of okayish quality get ignored and what possibly can be done about it. Maybe that's related to the high number of low quality question or maybe I have misunderstood something here. If some of the questions you linked are dupe targets for this question, you could vote for it.

Comment: @Trilarion Those questions I linked are in response to your comment about "33% of questions are ignored". You've merely discovered a symptom and are surprised that it's not discussed more. I'm pointing to the root problem; the symptoms are not surprising nor interesting. OP's question is a symptom as well; the solution is embedded in my first two comments on this post.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So you basically recommend that we first need to get rid of all low quality questions somehow before the medium quality questions have a decent chance not to be forgotten but to be answered again? The asker here can basically (except for getting rep and then curating like hell) do nothing? I think that this is not unreasonable and maybe should be an answer.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm gonna assume that your first sentence was sarcasm, hah; futile. The immediate solution to OPs problem is to write an interesting question. The long-term solution for the community is to not flood it with low quality questions. The more low quality questions exist, the more interesting OP will have to make their question. Too many users think "Oooh I have a thought, it must be worthy of being asked, this trivial endeavor cannot possibly be solved by reading existing questions because I am so smart!" This is what I've learned through experience; I used to enjoy the PHP tag...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree with you because i know that i used to be like that and browsing the python or flutter tag usually are either extremely low quality, easily solvable or incomprehensable. I might not ask the best questions, I do however try my best to have them be unique and understandable. focus on try. also that's why i asked here in there first place - what went wrong, is it my fault? how do i avoid this. It is just the problem of many people having many questions and most of them don't look for solutions or don't know what to look for, search terms etc.

Comment: @MaritnGe I can tell you care and are willing to listen and that's excellent. I really respect that and I hope that is how you've perceived my comments. It's unfortunately a situation of you vs. the void of crap.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus but people always complain about low quality questions and then you have questions with 4000 upvotes like "how can I do threading in python" without code or examples or anything breaking most of SOs best practice/rulse, maybe most the 'good and simple' questions have been asked already and now it is just duplicates of those or extremely specific questions that are hard to solve

Comment: @MonkeyZeus don't worry, i dind't interpret your comments about considering my post a part of the 'pile of crap'. thanks also!

Comment: As for "how can I do threading in python" receiving 4000 upvotes (assuming you're talking about https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653/2191572), well it was asked back in 2010 during Stack Overflow's infancy when there were much more relaxed rules an in general the site attracted serious developers and not just kids trying to plow through Codecademy. That question should very well be closed by today's standards but it has become a beacon for that exact low-barrier question with 19 visible answers and 4 deleted answers. The goal is for Googlers to hit that question first.

Comment: "most the 'good and simple' questions have been asked already and now it is just duplicates of those or extremely specific questions that are hard to solve" That definitely plays a role. The questions that most people have, don't need to be good (initially) in order to be solved and draw lots of visitors. They are also mostly asked already. More specific questions just get less attention naturally. Doesn't mean they can't become somewhat popular once they get an answer. Problem is how to match answerers with questions they might like to answer without wasting too much time.

Comment: The reason that page 50 is 2 days ago is simple:  People are asking insanely simple questions that could be answered by reading the documentation for less than 20 minutes.  This has become especially bad in the last 9 months.  Many people here are simply asking others to do their work or homework with zero initial effort.  The natural downside is that a legitimate, well-worded, question gets asked after a reasonable amount of investigation on the part of the asker, then immediately gets pushed to page 2.  (COVID-19: 19 questions in 20 should not have been asked.)

Comment: "What should I do if my question has been completely ignored?" <- Join the club :-(

Comment: It's just not clear what your question is. but I think you may be asking, in a round-about way, how to do something with command line interfaces that is impossible to do with command line interfaces (i.e. write to the screen at the same time as accepting input) so the lack of an answer may simply be because the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 75):

Start by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64994872/edit) your question to make it attractive for volunteers to answer. *Help us* help you!

- Make sure your code is *complete*. If people need to *reconstruct* your code, you are wasting their time. If people need to *guess* your code, you are gambling their effort.
- Make sure your question is *consistent*. The description is about *threads*, the code is about *processes*. These are very different things, and it is not clear what you are actually asking about. Figuring out if you are aware of this, if you know the difference, which one you actually ask about, takes time and effort.
- Make sure your presentation is *minimal* and *precise*. The goal (receiving and sending at once) is mentioned multiple times, yet always slightly different and never precisely. The issue is mentioned multiple times, yet wildly differently to the point of implying the desired state is the issue. Again, there is lots of effort to spend to even find out what question needs answering.

Even if you do all of that, there is no guarantee you *will* get answers – but it will greatly improve your chances. If it still sits idle, consider to [add a bounty or promote it in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). Ideally, cleaning up your question properly will also help *you* to help *yourself* – [if you are able to answer the question at some point, do not hesitate to do so.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) A good but difficult question is always deserving of an answer!

Answer (score 32):

First and foremost, you have to realize people answer questions as a hobby. This means

1. They do it only if it's rewarding (e.g. fun, philanthropic vibes, internet points etc)
2. They go for the path of least resistance
3. They stop when it annoys them

In other words, as someone wishing for their question to be answered, you have to

1. Provide a fun question, demonstrate helping you is a good cause or provide a lot of internet points
2. Make the question as easy to comprehend as possible
3. Definitely don't cross any red lines

There are too many questions to answer on Stack Overflow. To that end, people will answer those that takes the least effort to get to. Which is to say people go for questions with [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first, with particular emphasis on *minimal*: you want to simplify as much as possible but no simpler. This includes the prose, as well as the code.

Since your question doesn't seem particularly fun, you must either slap a bounty on it or demonstrate that helping you is a good cause and hope someone particularly charitable comes by. To do that, you typically show the (tonnes of) effort you've already put in.

Finally, you mustn't violate any of the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Specifically, your question isn't reproducible, and neither is the explanation concise. It lacks motivation, which probably stems from your confusion surrounding sockets and asynchronous IO.

You may observe that asking a good, attractive question is hard, and you'd be correct. You need to motivate people, you need to be a great writer and often you need to already know much about the topic. It takes practice and effort, but if you view this as an exercise of self-improvement it'd be worth it and I'll wish you luck on the journey.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer and also points to a big problem: people who can write excellent questions probably aren't those who need answers the most.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm curious as to what you mean by that.

Comment: @IanKemp I mean that Passer By makes an excellent case for writing high quality questions, but this requires also a lot of skills and somehow I cannot believe that question asking and question answering is completely independent. If you already know much about a topic and are able to search for background information to write a great question, you probably are able to answer the question by yourself. I'm sure there are lots of great writers out there, but they seem to have not so many questions they want to ask because they can answer themselves. Maybe that's wrong. ...

Comment: @IanKemp ...Maybe asking and answering are unrelated and the problem is just that most of us aren't great writers.

Comment: @IanKemp We want to build a library of knowledge, but we rely on the questions (buildings blocks) supplied by everyone mostly as is. Sure, there are great questions, but most questions are not usable for the library and need to be discarded. The question is if it has to be like this or if the whole process could be a bit more directed. I wouldn't know how, but maybe just saying "throw all your questions at us, we'll deal with them" will break down at some point in the future.

Comment: I agree with @Trilarion as I've become more familiar with topics, I am much less likely to ask questions rather than just try to figure it out myself. My drop off was also a little bit related to an attitude shift of the site, but that's another story.

Comment: @Trilarion Like most everything, writing is a skill. I think the software development world will be greatly improved when we all work on improving our human language writing (and speaking) in addition to our code writing.

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes you might have a genuinely unique question that no one is interested in answering for fear of being wrong (you will see this in the workplace as well), or your question might need more context such as a detailed explanation of your overall project, your complete current code, and/or just more details in general.

I try to go into detail on what research I have already performed and what issues are not currently being addressed in given documentation or within a programming language's community as a whole.

Better to give too much information than too little.

Comment: "The more information the merrier" has some drastically diminishing returns.  If your question doesn't fit on the page, you may want to invest in writing a minimal abstract at the beginning so folks can tell if the question is in their wheelhouse before diving into a page of code and research.

Comment: "Better to give too much information than too little." Please do not! The breadth of tangential information and fluff is precisely why I would pass on this question.

Comment: Well, if you give too few, you also attract closing votes as "needs details or clarity", or downvotes to hell with "what have you tried?" comments.

Comment: "that no one is interested in answering" -> no one... among the handful of viewers (a few tens, usually on most question)

Comment: @Pac0 The point is that *neither* "too few" nor "too much" information should be recommended. Yes, askers cannot magically know how much is needed, but they should try their best. Surrendering outright and aiming for "better give too much information" is a recipe to build bad questions.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes questions just slip between the cracks, even if they are well written, and especially if they are arcane or the tech is on the obscure side. Each question only has a very limited period of visibility until it falls out of view and if nobody with that knowledge is looking during that time you're out of luck.

The above posts give some good advice for making your question appealing, or at least not unappealing, but if you've done all that and still have no luck then don't take it to heart, it's probably not your fault. This is what bounties are for and they do really work. I just wish you didn't have to leave it a whole two days to use them as in my experience, if you don't get any bites within the first half a day you're not going to!

It's also worth noting that there are paid alternatives to SO if you're in a hurry and want to throw money at the problem, I don't know if I'm allowed to mention them by name though so I won't.

Comment: You might want to replace "the above post" with a link, or an answerers name, as depending on how answers are sorted the post above yours can differ.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like no one has mentioned this simple technique yet:

> If your question is ignored, publish it on Meta. `</tongue-in-cheek>`

No, this not a real technique you should use to promote your questions! You should only mention your question on Meta if you have a specific issue about *asking*, not about your technical matter. Posting on Meta guarantees more attention to your question *because* people don't abuse this, and each question-about-question is taken seriously by the community.

You should also be aware of [meta-effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) - if your question is not a real question, it will get closed more quickly.

Comment: I noticed it, it really wasn't my intent but the question went from <20 to >1000 views