# Is it unethical to vote down a question then answer it?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I come across bad questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103538/how-to-get-the-particular-data-between-the-string-identifiers/28103581#28103581). I don't think it is a particularly good question and it shows little effort. On the other hand, I can solve the problem. Is it unethical to write an answer to the problem and then downvote the question?

Or should I not be writing answers to these types of questions to begin with?

Comment: Poor questions tend to get closed. Closed questions tend to get deleted. When that happens, the answers get deleted as well. It's completely up to you to decide if you want to risk your effort being wasted like this or not. On the flip side, a magnificent answer may be all that's needed to salvage a poor question.

Comment: I've down-voted a question, voted to close it, answered it in a comment, and came back to vote to delete it. I can still sleep at night too. I probably wouldn't provide a "real" answer to such a thing though.

Comment: also related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No it's not *unethical*, voting is to simply give you opinion on the quality of the question. Even if you think the question isn't the best quality, doesn't mean you can't give an answer to the question. Poor questions can have good answers that *can* be helpful to others as well, although that tends to be rare. While most people here don't advise you to answer poor questions as it may add to the *noise* and *demise of the site*, it does not mean you can't answer the questions. This is a Q&A site after all.

That being said don't be surprised if the question is later removed for moderation reasons.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I was thinking about the _noise and demise of the site_ argument when I said "unethical". I'll try to avoid answering poor questions in the future.

Comment: @k_g Well some users think that if we answer poor questions will lead to those users asking more poor questions. Although I don't think that is completely true. Some new users often start with bad questions and improve their question quality over time as they become more experienced with the site. It really depends on who the user is.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two different cases here: poor questions that have actually something interesting in the problem itself, and can be edited to be good ones; and poor questions that just repeat stuff from earlier questions or don't have any idea to begin with and won't become good ones no matter what you did to them. First ones I'd answer, second ones I'd rather just comment on and vote for closing.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not unethical. But I would argue that you should answer the questions. I find myself many times in the same dilemma, when I know the answer to the OP's question (a lot of the times they are trivial beginner questions), but they have severe problems:

1. Lack of search effort, a lot of these questions *can* be found by a simple Google search
2. Lack of a small, complete reproduction of the errors. Many times, it's simply a copy-paste of their code.
3. The [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Many times people look for a solution to a specific problem which may not even make sense, instead of *describing* the problem. This doesn't always happen, but I see it quite often.

I'm not sure answering these type of questions actually leads people to ask better questions. There's the extensive FAQ and how to ask a question which explains a lot of the basics anyone should do before asking a question.

We should be encouraging people to ask quality questions by commenting on their posts on how they should improve. Sometimes, answering those question achieves the OPs desires without making them realize the question was poor.

Comment: While I agree that pointing people at the FAQ is a good thing, I don't think that it's a good solution to write "You question is bad. Go read the FAQ".  I think It's important to tell the asker *what* makes the question poor. If the asker is just pointed to the FAQ (like in the example above) he has to read the whole FAQ to figure out *what* he did wrong before he can even start to figure out how to do it better. I think that's very discouraging, especially if you feel like people are being rue, because you take the feedback on your question personally.

Comment: @Kritzefitz I'm not saying pointing him to the FAQ is the ultimate solution. It should be a reference for him to find how a good question should be asked, you should definitely try and help him improve his question by saying what you think will help improve the answer.

Comment: I didn't want to object to you. I just wanted to note it for everyone who comes by.

Comment: @Kritzefitz Of course, i just wanted to clarify what i ment :)

Answer (score -3):

I do this fairly often, but I'm firmly on the fence about it.

On the one hand, I don't want to encourage a complete lack of effort, research, or a minimal attempt on the part of the asker to actually solve their own problem, I'll flag to close and move on.  I might not even comment.

On the other hand, if it seems that the asker simply has no clue about what SO is about or its role in the StackExchange network, they don't realize there are more appropriate places to ask, or they simply don't know *how* to ask, I'll almost always comment (unless someone else already has), and there is a decent chance I'll try to answer it.  I frequently comment on questions from new users that "asking better questions leads to better answers" and point them at the FAQ, Help Center, How to Ask, or a combination thereof (depends on what they seem to need the most).

If it can be answered fairly quickly, I'll generally do it, but I still flag to close and sometimes paste from the text of the reason for the flag.  For example: earlier today, I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085163/excel-2010-date-hour-formating/28087385#28087385) with this:

> I had flag to close your question because it is off-topic for StackOverflow, which is a site for programming-related questions, but:
>
> *actual answer elided*
>
> In the future, please keep in mind that Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on SuperUser (http://superuser.com).

I suppose it boils down to what you consider to be a "bad" question versus a question poorly asked or simply asked in the wrong place.

Comment: If a question is completely off-topic I wouldn't answer it, if it is just a poorly asked question I would consider.

Comment: @KevinVoorn - Don't get me wrong - I don't think it's a *great* idea to be answering off-topic questions.  But, as Kritzefitz points out, helping new users stay on the Stack Exchange network (not necessarily SO) is a good thing.  This is why I find myself on the fence.  Personally, I would *love* to see more care from reviewers.  If more reviewers were more conscientious, this whole discussion might even be unnecessary. Reviewing other people's posts is a privilege, more people should treat it as such.  Then again, my niece wants a pony.

Comment: Helping people stay on SE who just demonstrated that they either did not check, care or comprehend what is and isn't off topic for SO before posting sounds like an extremely bad idea. Why do you think it adds anything of value to spoon-feed these users to keep them around, instead of clearly communicating (via closure, comments and _not answering_) that their question doesn't belong on SO? If you do want to guide them to the correct site, _post a comment and flag for closure_, if you want to guide them towards the answer, do that _in a comment_, but don't post an answer.