# Failed close vote audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I've just failed an audit when I chose "Leave Open" on the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8793978

The problem is, IMO, there's little merit in closing a question as "Unclear what you are asking" when it actually has two answers (including one that's accepted) by people who obviously understood the question just fine (the third answer is unclear in whether the poster misunderstood, or simply answered wrong). Not to mention that there's a comment that clarifies the intent further (though I understand that it would be more useful if that were an edit).

Now, I'm pretty sure the "Unclear what you are asking" are the typical close votes for "You didn't show any work of your own" kind of problem. This poses several problems IMO:

- The question isn't actually unclear - so this is a bad flag. It could use some rewording, but that should be handled by an edit rather than a close vote.
- There's no close vote for "SO is not a code writing service". As far as I can tell, the consensus (if any) seems to be that those kind of question should simply be downvoted (as in this case). The close vote seems redundant at best, and wrong at worst.
- The question actually has an accepted answer. Sure, it doesn't sound like an answer that anyone else is ever going ot use, but *closing it as unclear* seems iffy at best.

How should a case like this be properly handled? Should I add my own close vote which actually addresses the issues of the question? Should I edit the question since the apparent close reason is "Unclear what you are asking" (and in this case, vote for reopening)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, I'm pretty sure the "Unclear what you are asking" are the typical close votes for "You didn't show any work of your own" kind of problem

Sometimes but it shouldn't be used for this. You are right, the question is clear though, could use an edit to make it *more* clear.

> The question isn't actually unclear - so this is a bad flag. It could use some rewording, but that should be handled by an edit rather than a close vote.

This is correct.

> There's no close vote for "SO is not a code writing service". As far as I can tell, the consensus (if any) seems to be that those kind of question should simply be downvoted (as in this case).

Sure there is. Actually, there are two that can be used. "Too broad" fits as there are usually many ways to catch a fish (even primarily opinion based *could* work for some that don't show any effort). Another is "Questions asking for debugging help should show code, clear problem,..."

> The question actually has an accepted answer. Sure, it doesn't sound like an answer that anyone else is ever going ot use, but closing it as unclear seems iffy at best.

Accepted answer or not really has no bearing on whether it should be closed. That simply means it was useful to ***one*** person. This is not what SO is about. If it is only helpful to the OP, and if it most likely only ever will be, then it should be closed.

> How should a case like this be properly handled?

It should be left closed. Since it is already closed, there is no reason/way to add your own close vote without reopening but that doesn't seem worth it. You *could* edit to make it a little more clear but I'm not sure it's worth it in this case since this question is likely to not be edited enough to be reopened.

I've seen many questions closed for the wrong reason because either people are hasty, don't always understand which reason to use, or multiple reasons *can* fit.

The important thing is that these get closed if they are not a suitable question. But it would be nice if they are closed for the correct reason as to avoid this type of confusion. Maybe it is worth it to the powers that be to consider allowing certain rep users change close reasons that are obviously incorrect/misleading. But that's a topic for another post.

Comment: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)