# So we are trying to allow less obviously offensive content, but calling closing a Question Nazi-like behaviour doesn't count?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

I came across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable/277959#277959) answer while browsing meta SO, and thought that although it doesn't offend me personally, its one of the most offensive things to human decency I have found so far on this site. So I flagged it, explaining that it should probably be removed. My flag was declined.

I have recently heard many moderators stating (in the QA suggestion thread and multiple related threads about this topic) that Stackoverflow trys to reduce offensive content on its site. As this answer is heavily downvoted (-21) im inclined to think that a great deal of people found it either offensive or asinine. So I don't see the harm in deleting it directly. In fact I see some harm in leaving it up.

Mainly im trying to avoid wasting moderator time flagging further posts like this so I'd like to know what the appropiate course of action is when encountering such a post.

My flag text:

> Accusing the community of Nazi and Stalinist behavior for closing any
>   questions at all is deeply offensive and does not belong on this site.

Its worth noting that my flag text is not a hyperbole, thats almost exactly what the answer actually says.

The Answer of the moderator to my flag:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

Comment: `-22`. The community has already spoken.

Comment: @Cerbrus -22 means still visible though. Disliked, but visible. I thought that removing it alltogether would have been better there.

Comment: That guy seems to have some kind of grudge against SO. After reading the post, I figured this would be a good candidate for a delete vote.

Comment: Ah, ohwell. Lets hope some more people agree. I can't delete vote yet.

Comment: Well, I did flag it as "rude or abusive" - another chance for the mods to kick it.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but: a) isn't *deleting* opinions of meta you disagree with kind of counter-productive. For three people, apparently, that post represents their views. If the post didn't exist, would the other two just have posted their own answer?; and b) making a historical comparison about book-burning isn't that big of a deal. It's not a core part of the post, either. If it offends you, you could edit out those three words.

Comment: @TZHX I was under the impression that the community didn't want to leave obviously offensive content around. I hesitated editing and bumping a question last active a year ago. Also, it doesn't offend me personally, but I think it does a great deal of people (its pretty obvious why).

Comment: @TZHX: _"Style-guide Nazis are the reason I rarely bother with Stack Overflow these days. Your comment nicely illustrates another reason for you to desist your pointless curation."_ The post is filled with that kind of borderline-insulting opinion-based junk. This doesn't add any value to SO whatsoever. It actively discourages users from contributing to SO.

Comment: @TZHX For us Germans being compared to Nazis is certainly way more offensive than you might imagine. So yes, it certainly hurts our feelings and as such is offensive.

Comment: Also, the answer is full of _"Boo! Censorship!"_ rants. As soon as a answer starts comparing closing votes with censorship, in my opinion, it loses _all_ validity.

Comment: I wouldn't even be sure what to edit there. Almost everything in there is either baseless rambling or outwardly agressive.

Comment: @piet.t we see the word "Nazi" on meta quite frequently from people complaining about their question bans, etc. most of the time it's just taken as a signal someone is having a little rant & summarily ignored. Having a post heavily downvoted serves as a signal of "this isn't welcome here", deleting it just makes it go away for some people.

Comment: Yea, let's stop deleting posts. _*Cough*_

Comment: @Cerbrus If it were posted today, out of the blue, I'd absolutely be in favor of deleting it -- but bringing up a post from a year ago and complaining that it uses a metaphor you think *other people* may find distasteful when you can just edit out three (or four) words? I don't see the point.

Comment: If we don't delete answers on SO for being blatantly *wrong*, we should do the same on meta for answers we heavily disagree with.

Comment: @TZHX: Editing that post isn't an option since there'd be nothing left of it.

Comment: It seems to have been done. The "offensive" words have been removed.

Comment: @TZHX If I edited out everything that would merit deletion in my opinion, I would have to cat 90% of the post.

Comment: In it's current state, what do you find offensive about the post other than that you disagree with it?

Comment: Maybe not offensive, but actively harmful to SO since it's actively discouraging users from contributing to the site. And now it's been edited, the post has been pushed up the "active" page. Which doesn't help at all.

Comment: @TZHX Its just agressive and rambling. Alot of agression and rambling. Offensive historical references aside (sic), there is plenty more in this post to be angry at. Comparing deleting posts to book burning is far more egregious then just making nazi references imo, and so is insinuating that SO will bring about some police state.

Comment: Its worth noting I refrained from editing mainly because as to not bump this toxic post to the front page for more people to see.

Comment: So you thought you'd post a *new topic* on the front page linking to it?

Comment: @TZHX at least people know what they are getting into with this one. Also I did try to flag first, but a mod declined my flag.

Comment: People of even moderate intelligence can tell that post is a rant before they get into mentioning Nazi's and Stalin.

Comment: And rants shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: Not much of a rant, really; there's actual argumentation for the conclusion there.

Comment: @Magisch A possible answer to your question is: we Germans are here a very small group, compare to others. For the others this word isn't an offendation. Don't make a big deal of it. It just a word. And keep in mind: the second world war and "Nazis" is now a part of our history. Not more and not less.

Comment: @TZHX generally to bypass content filters of course ;)

Comment: @reporter not for everyone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Nazism

Comment: That answer is factually wrong and a rant, but it should not be deleted.

Answer (score 37):

For [`fsck`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck)'s sake, can we **please stop** being hypothetically offended on other peoples' behalfs? If you're not offended by it, and have no evidence that someone else is so deeply affected by it that they're unable to even leave a comment voicing their approbation, then just leave it be.

Referring to  Nazis is not *in itself* offensive. Comparing someone's restrictive behavior to them is a lot closer, but it's also a standard idiom that's been [the subject of an episode of one of the most popular prime-time American TV shows ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soup_Nazi).

The answer is full of hyperbole, and it's making a point that I strongly disagree with, but **that doesn't mean that it needs to be deleted**. N.B. that it's actually making a point, too -- there's real arguments brought forth for the conclusion, however much the rest of us find the point unsatisfactory.

I don't even really think it needs to be edited, but I went ahead and did it for you anyways. Next time, please just do it yourself. It's [not that hard to find substitutes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202954/alternative-expression-for-xyz-nazi).

Comment: You intentionally misspelled something. I'm so offended now!

Comment: Not at all, @Cerbrus; Unix utilities are practically begging to be used as curse words. I would have thought that was `grep`ping obvious. :)

Comment: Ah, unix. Didn't think of that. Suddenly I'm not offended!

Comment: Thank god (oops hope i'm not offending anyone with that) for this droplet of sanity. Deleting posts amounts to censorship in the poster's view and from there it's not that much a step to pull a [Godwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_Law). It may be over the top but so is classifying it as obviously offensive. It's not like the guy is posting pictures of Swastika's or something!

Comment: I always thought the swastika was a rather beautiful and striking symbol (just from a pure design aesthetic). It's kind of a shame it has so many negative connotations now. It would actually play out like a comedy to see someone expressing his thoughts against heavy moderation using such colorful expressions to then simply have his post deleted.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty basic symbol, @Ike (with an extensive pre-Nazi history, as I'm sure you know); a structure that's quite easy to come up with while doodling. Part of the reason people see them everywhere and get excited about it, I suppose. I have often wondered whether I'll live to see the return of the fashionably-acceptable Chaplin mustache or the general usability of the swastika (of whichever handedness).

Comment: This gets my vote. Having a strong opinion that has the tang of venom on meta will guarantee you plenty of downvotes, but I don't see why that needs to be censored with deletion or finger pointing. Downvote and move along, plenty of real things to be offended by, such as a Good Day to Die Hard. Jeepers that movie is blasphemy.

Answer (score 9):

It seems a little counterproductive to delete a rant of that nature, since it gives another flimsy excuse for such people to go off on tirades about SO.

Moreover, while exhibiting Godwin's Law in such an obnoxious fashion is certainly tasteless, it's preferable if Meta can be run in such a way as to avoid taking offense wherever possible, even at rather nasty things. This allows discussion to function more freely on the side of the site that is dedicated less to the strictly professional knowledge base and more to hashing out policies and explanations of same.

Just leave it up as an example of downvoted wrongheadedness.

Comment: *it's preferable if Meta can be run in such a way as to avoid taking offense wherever possible* Yes, very good point! Too bad you dismiss his opinion as tirade of wrongheadedness. Over-moderation does exist and it can *and will* hurt the wrong people sometimes. Spending time trying to contribute something good, only to get hit by close-votes / downvotes / negative comments is a very dissatisfying experience that can damage user's motivation to try to contribute again.

Answer (score 2):

> Im inclined to think that a great deal of people found it either offensive or asinine. So I don't see the harm in deleting it directly. In fact I see some harm in leaving it up.

I don't believe all down voters were offended.  I would suspect the down voting was based on them not agreeing (perhaps with the tone more than the points being made).

I don't believe there is any harm in the post because it offers a different perspective to the discussion.  In the grand scheme of things I always find it useful to hear the arguments for and against, including extreme views.  If such opinions exist then they should be expressed, not suppressed.

Arguably, using Nazi wording should be moderated.  Let's put this in perspective.  The OP for this discussion is based in Germany (according to his SO profile) so obviously it doesn't take a lot of convincing that maybe that should be edited out of the answer under discussion.  However, I wouldn't go as far as removing the complete answer based on that one possible edit.

Comment: *"I would suspect the down voting was based on them not agreeing (perhaps with the tone more than the points being made)"* Yes I agree that they were probably not agreeing. But if you look at my answer below (currently at -13) I think it's clear that the tone has little to do with it. Groupthink is strong here on meta. If you voice a different opinion you will get downvoted....

Answer (score -18):

I actually think the guy has a point.

The fact that he is now ranked at -24 or something further solidifies my view that the 'Stack Overflow Community' is actually doing the things that he is ranting about.

Yes, the community can be trigger happy. Pedantic. Passive-aggressive. I get a very in-crowd feeling about what is happening on meta some times (e.g. close-vote 'hunts'). There seem to be people here that are spending hours per day moderating. Good for you but there is such a thing as over-moderation and the poster is complaining about that.

Yes he is using hyperboles and pulling a Godwin. Yes it's a rant. 
[But](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/) [he](http://theexceptioncatcher.com/blog/2012/09/stackoverflow-is-a-difficult-community-to-participate-in/) [is](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7650799) [not](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.iog89foi6) [alone](https://twitter.com/teemu/status/644498099197620228). I have seen more posts saying essentially the same thing.

In my experience when you start to get feedback of this type, it is to be taken very seriously. This one post represents hundreds of posts *not written* that amount to the same thing. Not very many people write a post on a website they are disappointed or pissed about. They just go somewhere else.

When people think they are not being heard, or are being ignored, they sometimes decide to make more noise. This is what he is doing. But the reason is that he cares. He wants SO to do better.

Personally I agree with his view that the whole premise that we are building a library of great questions and answers and aggressive moderation helps in making sure people can find what they are looking for is false. *Google* helps me find what I am looking for. In my opinion, if result A ranks higher than result B, but result A is marked as duplicate of B, that marking is unhelpful! More people are coming in to result A than to result B, therefore result A *is more important*.

Anyhow, take it easy with the close- and downvotes. They are negative emotion in my book. Come here to *upvote* instead it will make users happy!

Comment: If something is poor quality, not fit for the QA format, or otherwise undesirable on SO as determined by community consensus why shouldn't it be downvoted/closed/deleted?

Comment: Community consensus? As cool as the regular moderators are, and though they may feel like they are a community, they represent only a tiny fraction of the total userbase. And they are definitely NOT a good representation of 'the community' as a whole because they are a very distinct group of heavy users that spend many hours here. The Q&A format is only loosely applicable to Meta, and 'undesirable' is such a subjective term. *I* desire to hear his voice. Am I considered part of this community? I'm certainly not in agreement with your 'consencus'...

Comment: Do you really find it necessary to drag the argument from there over here? Most of this answer doesn't address the question of the appropriateness of that answer. If you want to contribute to the other discussion, do so with an answer under the other question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's a good point... For me somehow whether the answer has any merit is part of determining whether it is offensive... I now realize that this may not be completely logical reasoning. However  I think you can't deny there is a strong relation about someone ranting about closing and another post saying that rant should be deleted... I'd call it irony.

Comment: @StijndeWitt community consensus is reached if enough people vote to close/delete/downvote and nobody or not enough people contest that. Thats a basis upon which the SO community moderation works. And moderators (the diamond people) usually dont engage in this because they have more important things to do, but their votes are considered community consensus by the system aswell.

Comment: I won't deny that irony/relationship, @StijndeWitt, but I also don't think that just saying "you fascist mods are going to delete this, aren't you" is enough to defer deletion. It's the fact that the post actually puts together a cogent argument-- however much it's disagreed with -- that gives it value.

Comment: I call anyone using moderation skills 'a moderator', sorry. I know the distinction between the elected moderators and SO staff and us mere mortals  :)  The point is that SO's voting system is like a democracy where only a tiny percentage of people actually ever casts a vote. If it would happen in the general elections it would be called a crisis, here, we call it concensus...

Comment: @JoshCaswell Great to see that we agree on that. The post *does* build a coherent, on-topic argument, even if its using hyperboles and godwins to do so. For me it touches a nerve. I too feel SO is over-moderated.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I must disagree. If you remove all the hyperbole and agressiveness and useless stuff, there is maybe 10 words left in that post.

Comment: I concede that the tone of the post is strong but he does make a very clear point. "why shouldn't it be downvoted/closed/deleted?" To me is the wrong question to ask. Why *should* it? Live and let live. Imho, deletion should be a rare event, reserved for extreme cases.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Again, if you want to discuss that, go over to that meta post,  This post isn't here to discuss whether or not SO should completely remove all of it's standards and turn itself into exactly the type of sites it was created to replace due to how ineffective those other sites were/are.

Comment: @StijndeWitt *"I call anyone using moderation skills 'a moderator'"* By that definition, you are also a moderator.

Comment: @KevinB Yup, but only when using those skills  :)  Just like anyone driving a car is a driver.