# Is my question really too broad? I don't believe it is

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

I've asked a question on Stack Overflow about [How a relation works in SQL vs NOSQL Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456522/how-a-relation-works-in-sql-vs-nosql-mongodb)

Currently the question I asked was put on hold for:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I believe I explained my problem, even with a real time example. How can this question be too broad and asking me to add more details?

If people commented on and answered my question, how can this be too broad? They wouldn't have done so if my question is really too broad.

Comment: About a small detail of your queston here: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable)

Comment: Hmm...you asked 3 or 4 questions there, so the answer would be very long. For example a long answer of one of your questions: [SQL (MySQL) vs NoSQL (CouchDB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559411/sql-mysql-vs-nosql-couchdb)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, your question is too broad as you ask us to explain a concept, namely 'relations' in the context of NoSql databases compared to RDBMS. For that reason I close voted your question.

That is too broad as it requires a more theoretical explanation and comparison of the techniques in both systems so it becomes possible to see if and how they are comparable. Answers would need to address read operations, cascading deletes, the ACID nature of operations where relations are involved, to name a few.

> But, in NOSQL, I heard it has No relation. Is that right?

The Q/A format is not very well suited to be a tutorial. You seem to be looking for that given your above statement.

You claim that the your question isn't too broad because it has an answer. But honestly the answer is as broad and open-ended as your question which your comment also suggests:

> I understand your example. But, doesn't the relation looks like SQL? Then, what that differentiates SQL & NOSQL? I feel same. That's my point!

That answer is an attempt to provide an answer but it fails due to the broadness of the question.

Thankfully you provided some examples but you should have taken that a few steps further. You could have implemented a small mock-up where you showed how you worked with your example document to do a fetch operation to find out you can only process 20 things per second. You try a couple of options and then ask a question if there are ways to improve it so you can reach 100 things per second. Answers to that question will either explain the option `boost_perf`, or explain indexing or explain how you should have designed your document structure in the first place. Some of them might expand on how there are no relations in NoSql databases.