# Should I close a question as "Unclear what you are asking" by only looking at its content?

Tags: support, questions, comments, vote-to-close

I just want to know what should I do in this situation:

A user posts a question but he/she did not write a clear question i.e. there isn't an actual "question" in the post. Usually, I would just close these questions as unclear. But later, some other users asked the OP for clarification and the OP explained and asked his question in the comments.

Should I still close it as unclear? The question itself does not contain an actual question, but one of its comments does. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable

Comment: You write this question as if you never have heard of editing in the SO context.

Comment: Comments don't count. Either it's in the post, or it's unclear. But you can edit the post.

Comment: When in doubt, just close it. Welcome to the Stackoverflow Police!

Comment: Did you know what he wanted, even though he didn't ask it in question form? If the answer is yes, then it was not unclear to you, you were just being pedantic.

Comment: @TylerH That's a good point.  Making it look more obviously like a question might be helpful for people who aren't as proficient in English though.  You often see the opposite - things which look like questions but aren't?

Comment: If a question is unclear, it should be closed. If the OP gets around to clarifying, they should do so by editing the question rather than by answering in a comment. However, the question goes to "on hold" status for being unclear, which is a great opportunity to recover from this mistake to prevent closure.  That being said, if I see a clarification in a comment, I usually make the edit myself rather than close-vote. However, if there is no clarifying comment yet in response to a clarifying question posed by someone in the comments, I close-vote.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If editing the information in the comments into the question makes the question clear, do that.  If you're suggesting an edit, make sure to leave a clear edit summary so the edit isn't rejected.  (You have full edit privileges but future readers of this question may not.)

If the question is still unclear, go ahead and vote to close.  You may wish to leave a comment asking the asker to `[edit]` their question to add information; that `[edit]` will become a clickable link that opens the editor.

Comment: Are there more links that can be entered like that `[edit]` link?  Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: @matthew http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/153008

Comment: That's a great link! I've been copying the link to mcve, help and edit manually :|

Comment: `Just wanted to test the [edit] markdown.` displays: Just wanted to test the [edit] markdown.

Comment: When making a edit suggestion as non 2k-er, remember that reviewers CANNOT see the comments without clicking on the question itself, make sure to explicitly state in the edit comment that the information comes from the original comments. (Not everyone realizes this)

Comment: @Matthew or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 13):

Just to add one more reference to the suggestion to edit instead of close. The flag option for "should be closed..." states:

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, **and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing**.

(Emphasis mine)

You've stated the vote-to-close functionality of course which does not have this statement. Just thought I'd mention it since it's related.

Answer (score 12):

I tend to think of comments as "metadata" about the question.  They are easy to miss (and even collapsed in some cases) and can be easily deleted with no trace so any information in them isn't really part of the question.  As said in the other answer, if you see something useful in comments that should be in the question, go ahead and edit it in to make it clearer.

However, always judge questions on the contents of the question itself.  If the question (including any edits that you choose to make to improve it) isn't clear, then the question isn't clear.  Even if you vote to close, you can always take it back later if it is clarified, and even a closed question can be reopened if it is improved.

Answer (score 0):

Comment section is used for clarification of doubts regarding the question. It's often used by the people to get cleared about the question itself. When question becomes clear in comment section, it's the responsibility of the Person asking the question to make the needful edits in the question so that if In case, someone in future does face the same doubt, he/she may not have to go through the comments to get clarified.
 
**The only thing that matters is the question should be clear in the question itself.**

Comment: Don't mark it as in need of moderator attention. That's overkill for 'edit needed'. Mods exist to deal with problems that the normal user base can't.

Answer (score -2):

No one has to close a question, and there's no virtue in being the first to do so.  I try to give posters the benefit of the doubt.  If a comment leads to better question, so much the better.  Comments give them a chance to edit the post so it has a real question.

Occasionally I get frustrated by people who close a question simply based on format or style details, or their own lack of understanding about the underlying problem.  Fortunately I have enough rep to reverse some closures and write a useful answer.

To me closure is most appropriate when it is clear the poster is not making any effort to correct the question based on comments.  In other words, if the comments, or even answers aren't leading to resolution.  Premature closure shuts other contributors out of the dialog.

Comment: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Answer (score -3):

> Should I close a question as “Unclear what you are asking” by only
>   looking at its content?

This is a close-ended question, but an Yes or No answer might not be constructive.

I think it's safe to assume an unclear question (a question where is hard to determine what is actually asked) comes from a new user not familiar with how Stackoverflow works.

As you mention in your question that follow-up comments do contribute to clarify the question, it might also be the case of a new user not being familiar with the edit functionality.

Instead of "waiting 0 seconds and voting to close" I would:

- give new users a chance to understand where they went wrong, by posting a comment inviting them to edit their own question. [edit] magic link is great and will definetely help a user become aware such magic links exist. Personally, I didn't know they existed before reading this question, and seems like this is true for lots of others (maybe a majority?)
- edit the question yourself and maybe post a comment to explain why (again, this would help new users)
- either way, this implies the user has more than 0 seconds (so has a fighting chance) to correct the issue him/herself
- mark it as "unclear"

My perspective here might not appeal to those that have 0 tolerance to new-comers that don't bother to read the site policy, but then again, how many of us didn't miss part or all policy on some service/product/website?