# How is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709964/create-image-from-base64-encoded-string) has been closed as Too Broad, but the latest edit seems to have cleared up any confusion.

The accepted answer is precise and helpful, exactly what I was looking for, and demonstrates that the question was perfectly clear if you know any Swift. I think it should be reopened because it is no longer too broad.

Comment: related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: It certainly contains aspects that make the question sound too broad.  I think "_Please provide any answers or reference similar articles described using Swift_" threw a bunch of red flags.

Comment: @ryanyuyu that's superfluous to me, the core question in the first two paragraphs contains no ambiguity

Comment: @mjr if it's superfluous, then edit it out of the question.

Comment: That's basically a "I have tried nothing, halp me" (too broad) question no matter whether it really is. Not only did you not show any attempt to solve a part of the problem (which btw consists of multiple problems (too broad)) I also find it hard to believe you couldn't find any real resources about doing what you are asking. As in I don't know anything about swift, but finding a dupe was a 1 minute job.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I think you're being way too hard on this question. It's a reasonably-scoped question about a common problem, far better written than most of these we see. As a subject matter expert, I wouldn't be irritated to see this pop up in a feed and could even find it useful as a reference.

Comment: Anything in specific I said that is wrong?

Comment: Mostly agreed with Brad Larson here, @PeeHaa, although I too was looking for dupes the instant I saw it. (I was trying to find a narrower one than the one you found, but thanks for tacking it down.) I also found myself somewhat irritated by the conveyed attitude of the asker, but more because of the "I can't read Objective-C" bit, which I find utterly nonsensical for such a small task (the API is identical).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bad question, but I bet the last sentence of

> Please provide any answers or reference similar articles described using Swift.

triggered a negative response in reviewers. Typically, when you see something like that you're dealing with a broad survey of a question or one looking for a list of resources instead of a particular solution.

I've reworded the question to focus on the specific task: taking in a base64-encoded string and converting that to a UIImage. That seems appropriately scoped, and is answerable in a concise manner, so I've reopened it.

Comment: Looks like it might be a dupe now.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Yeah, at first it looked like the duplicate was for the inverse, but the code for decoding in Swift was recently edited into accepted answer on the target. It's a little buried, and missing from the other answers there, but the duplicate marking should probably be fine.

Comment: It is a tad hard to see; I actually missed it the first time I looked at it. I've edited the title again to hopefully make it a bit clearer that conversion in both directions is covered. The original version of the question does mention both.

Answer (score 2):

The canned answers are general. It is often a matter of personal opinion as to which canned answer someone finds best. The actual close reason is the most popular one.

The question linked to does not provide any details of what they have already tried. The middle paragraph can be interpreted as wanting a tutorial. The final sentence starts *"Please provide any answers or reference ..."* and so is asking for off site resources. If the question were reopened as "not too broad" then, I believe, it would be closed again for wanting tutorials and links to external sites.

Comment: This isn't really a large enough task to warrant a tutorial.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Perhaps you are correct but I know little on that subject area so with no details of what had been attempted plus the middle paragraph it looked to me like wanting a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

After a post is put on hold if it is edited it automatically enters the reopen vote review queue.  Unfortunately after 7 days a question goes from being on hold to being closed.  Once that happens edits the question no longer will enter it into the reopen vote queue.  Since the OP edited it after the question was "closed" all it did was bump the question to the top of the active tab.  If no one acted on it while it was visible again then normally the closed question will float off into purgatory or get deleted by the roomba.

The only way now to get the question reopened is to do what you did and bring it to somewhere where other people can weigh in and act.