# Marked as Answered however people keep down-voting my answer

Tags: discussion

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879520/how-to-write-a-single-random-word-from-a-txt-file-in-a-label-using-c-sharp-lang/41879606#41879606), recently someone asked a vague question which I tried to answer as best I could. Clearly it helped the OP as he marked it answered, however I am getting down-votes on this answer.

I made sure that all my lines of code work, and in my opinion do what the user has asked, in some way or another. Why would others down vote my correct and accepted answer, when my code is well explained and also functioning properly ?

Comment: Just because it helped the person who asked the question doesn't mean it is a good solution.

Comment: Agreed, however, my answer included logical steps on how to approach the situation using basic coding. It will clearly do what the user has asked, without going overboard and providing complex coding.

Comment: Also, it might not have been the best idea to link to your actual answer, as the [meta-effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) is pretty common here.

Comment: @leaf Just goes to show.. that some regardless of what is answered will still down-vote when they see that others have done the same. All I did was try to help.

Comment: @Rizzo That doesn't show that at all.  It simply means that they agreed with the other user's assessment of the quality of the answer.

Comment: No point in arguing about this, I just wanted to see why all the downvotes.

Comment: FWIW, that `new Random().Next(...)` thing is of itself worthy of a downvote because [of this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/3764814).

Comment: Also, if you can re-use an answer it is more likely the question you're answering is a duplicate. Better find and flag those instead of re-inventing the wheel with a fragmentation of knowledge all over the place.

Comment: Well, your answer is wrong.  If `word.Length` = 20, and the next random picked is 20, then your answer would cause an IndexOutOfLengthException, as `word` has a maximum index of 19.  Tada.

Comment: @Will The parameter to `Next` is exclusive, not inclusive.

Comment: The Op finally posted, stating that my answer helped. At the end of the day that is what matters. Thank you all for you feedback

Comment: @Servy damn, that's right.  Pit of success, but I fell into it and still failed.  Guess the question that was +2 that added the `- 1` was the one that was actually wrong.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, isn't that a different case though? ``This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times.``

Comment: see also: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: @Rizzo well, the question asked for random *words* (in plural). So using this pattern in a loop to get several words would expose the issue right away.

Comment: 1 random word at a time

Comment: There are just things you don't ever write as recommendation on SO - new'ing up `Random` inline (or next to usage) is one of these things (along with SQL injection). Such answers essentially guarantee that OP will come back next hour/day with another "this does not work. Help!!!" question and multiple people will have to spent time explaining why suggestion was bad. So downvoting also saves SO from one bad question next day.

Comment: The helpfulness of your answer to the asker is shown by the accept-mark - the quality and usefulness for others by the up- or downvotes. And SO's primary goal is not helping this one user but creating a repository of quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downvoting is privilege awarded to any user with [125 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Although you may think your answer is useful, someone else may not have the same opinion. They're choosing to express that by downvoting.

The same goes for an accepted answer. The OP can choose to accept any answer. But it's only an opinion.

In this case, the OP thought your question was useful so he/she accepted it. However, other folks in the community thought it wasn't so they downvoted it.

Definitely keep participating! It takes time to learn what makes a good question and answer. A great way to learn is to pick a tag you're interested in and read the top voted answers/questions for that tag. Also, follow the top users for that tag.

For example, I'm excited about ruby, so I search for the "ruby" tag by typing `[ruby]` into the search bar. Based on the [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) I'm able to see top questions, answers, and users and learn from them.

Welcome to SO and good skills moving forward!

Answer (score 23):

> someone asked a vague question which I tried to answer

That's a problem.  You shouldn't do that.  When a question is unclear work with the question author to clarify the question and *then* answer it, once it is no longer unclear.

> Clearly it helped the OP as he marked it answered, however I am getting down-votes to this answer.

Clearly those other people don't think the answer is useful. Just because the OP thinks it's useful doesn't mean everyone else is obligated to agree.

> I made sure that all my lines of code work,

That, alone, doesn't mean that the answer is useful, or a correct answer.

> and in my opinion do what the user has asked

You just stated before that the user's question was unclear, so it's your opinion that you *don't* know if you answered the question asked, because you don't know what the question is asking.

> Why would others down vote my correct and accepted answer,

Perhaps they disagree that it's correct.  You have yourself said that you don't know if it's correct as you don't know what the question is asking, so it certainly seems reasonable that others would agree.  They may also feel that it's not a useful post despite not having factual inaccuracies, as there are any number of factors that can influence the usefulness of an answer beyond just its technical accuracy (it's correctness, being a complete answer to the question, being clear, avoiding poor practices, whether it adds to other existing answers, plagiarising content, etc.).

Comment: Agreed, however, The OP wants to get a word from a file - I provided that piece of coding stating all assumptions i took. The OP want to get a `random` word from a file. I also provided this information.

Comment: I also explained how he could actually display whatever is inside the file, insde a label or textbox.

Comment: @Rizzo That you stated all of the assumptions you made doesn't mean it's okay to make a ton of assumptions about the situation.  The point remains that providing a correct and quality answer *to a different question than what is actually being asked* isn't actually a useful answer *to the question being asked*.

Comment: I made only a few assumptions regarding what the OP has in his text file, and since he marked as Answered it seems that my assumptions were correct?

Comment: I agree to everything that you are saying, however this is the first time I have seen something like this.

Comment: @Rizzo That's not a safe assumption to make.  I saw someone just a few hours ago accept an answer that they specifically said doesn't answer their question at all just because the person clearly spent so much time writing it and they wanted to acknowledge their efforts on it, even though it was both off topic to the question and had a number of factual inaccuracies.

Comment: @Rizzo To add to that, I also, fairly commonly, see people accept the first answer that comes along, only to actually test it out hours/days later, and come back and say that it didn't work.  (This is certainly more common than the previous case of someone accepting an answer they know is wrong; despite me seeing it earlier today, and it thus being on my mind, it's pretty uncommon for the OP to state that they *know* the answer is wrong when accepting it, it's more common for them to just not realize it doesn't work (or doesn't work for them).)

Comment: I dont think that is the case in this particular instance.  The OP replied stating that my answer has indeed helped.

Comment: @Rizzo That means it's not the first case.  It doesn't mean it isn't the second.  In many cases the people asking the question simply aren't in a position to realize why a given solution isn't actually a good and correct answer, for exactly the reason they needed to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: True, however this was a very simple task of displaying a random word in a label/text box. If this was achieved then isn't it safe to say that the answer was correct?

Comment: As stated above, there were other answers which were actually incorrect which were received far better than mine by this community.

Comment: @Rizzo Not necessarily.  For example, the solution might be [improperly using a random number generator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342322/marked-as-answered-however-people-keep-down-voting-my-answer/342323?noredirect=1#comment437591_342322) resulting in poor random number generation, which may not be apparant with a trivial test, even if would cause problems in the application, just to provide some arbitrary example.

Comment: @Rizzo Arguing that an even worse answer didn't get as many downvotes doesn't make your answer good or not worth downvoting.  There'll always be a worse answer.  That doesn't mean that only the single worst answer on SO should ever be downvoted.  You also brought a lot of attention to your post.  You specifically went out and told a bunch of people to go evaluate the quality of your post, and as such it has gotten more votes than it otherwise would have.  Most bad posts just don't get enough attention to attract many downvotes.

Comment: True. You are correct in saying this. I am just baffled/worried by the amount of bad reviews this is generating for me, regarding something so small which the user isn't even taking into consideration.

Comment: When you answer a low quality question, you're moving in the direction of making it very hard to delete said low quality question. If you're going to do that, you should at least make the question not low quality first. In this case, you can't do that, only the OP can, therefore answering it beforehand is counter-productive. The op will get their answer, the question will never be improved, and if your answer has a positive score the question will never go away unless it is closed and then delete voted by 3 high rep users.

Comment: @KevinB Well, not automatically anyway.  Manual intervention is still a route (as happened here a few seconds after you posted your comment).