# What to do when you find the answer to your question but it would be long

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

I currently have an active bounty on one of [my questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162258/rtf-to-html-removes-the-html-tables?noredirect=1#comment71607130_42162258) Alongside placing the bounty I have still been looking into the issue.

As the subject can get quite complex it has taken myself quite a while to come to an acceptable solution (acceptable, not complete), one that I have now found. However, this required editing and changing lots of the source files of the 3rd party library I was using, the one linked to in my question (the code project one).

As such any answer I can write would essentially be either:

1. Tutorial based: I would be saying edit this files with these lines, add this class etc. quite a lot of.
2. Off site: I could just poste the code to GitHub or wherever and point to that in my answer and say that the code in the question is exactly the same to get it to work.

Obviously these two approaches both have drawbacks, and even seem like it would make the question eligible for closure:

1. Too Broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be **too long for this format**.
2. Off-topic: ...**software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**...

What should I do in this situation and future ones like it?

Comment: Since you don't have any answers yet, is it possible for you to tweak your question so that the answer wouldn't be so big?

Comment: @BSMP Probably not, the subject, and answer, was bigger than I thought it would be. I thought there might be some small API that might do it but none of them seem to. I ended up having to edit an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not your specific question is "too broad" is outside the scope of this answer, but in the general case, you have a lot of options. Bear in mind that the ultimate goal is to help future readers, noting that link-only answers are discouraged primarily because rotted links fail to help future readers.

1. Close the question, if you feel it is too broad.
2. Do nothing. Personally I'm not a big fan of this option. I feel like when I find an answer to my own question I should at least follow up to help others, with the hope that some day when *I* have a question I'll get some karmic return. That said doing nothing (for now) is a good way to see if the community feels the same way about whether the question should be closed.
3. *"Off site: I could just poste the code to GitHub or wherever and point to that in my answer and say that the code in the question is exactly the same to get it to work."* -- Sure. Post it as a comment and leave it at that. Helpful and appropriate if you don't have the time or desire to write a full answer.
4. *"Tutorial based: I would be saying edit this files with these lines, add this class etc. quite a lot of."* -- If you are willing to put the time into this, post it as an answer if you feel it would be helpful to others.

Those are your options. However...

There isn't really a "correct" approach here and none of us can tell you what you should do. Which of the above options you choose depends on how you personally want to balance spending time vs. posting a full answer, and that's entirely your decision.

You could also close it as too broad, although since you were able to find a specific working answer, I *could* see that as a possible argument for it not actually being too broad. I'll let somebody else debate that one, though. You might find some useful perspective on that in [Do "too broad" questions become less broad after an acceptable answer is given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223454/do-too-broad-questions-become-less-broad-after-an-acceptable-answer-is-given) and [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432).

If you feel the answer is more work than you are willing to put in, that's totally fine, just as it would be totally fine for you to not post an answer to somebody *else*'s question if you didn't have the time or desire to do so. Perhaps pretending that you were not the asker of the question could help you make a decision.

The only thing we can tell you is that if you choose to only link to GitHub or whatever, do it in a comment, and if you want to write something more detailed, do it in an answer. Beyond that it's really just your choice.

Answer (score -2):

Since you know that the question merits closure for being Too Broad, vote to close it as Too Broad.

If you feel like writing up a lengthy tutorial for the sake of others, there are plenty of places one can host an in-depth tutorial, SO simply isn't one of those places.

Comment: It's not that the question is too broad, it's that the answer I found is too broad. That doesn't necessarily mean someone can't find a short answer though. In that case would leaving the question unanswered be a valid approach?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Looking at your specific question, it sure looks Too Broad to me.

Comment: Also I can't vote to close my question because of the bounty