# Why can't I be working on my knight moves?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, unclear

My self-answered question 
[D3: Simulation of a knight's moves on an infinite chess board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804200/d3-simulation-of-a-knights-moves-on-an-infinite-chess-board) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFqIg.png)) was closed as unclear.

I feel this was done just because the questions are unusual, and don't fit into "fix the code" category.

And then, many complain: Where are interesting questions? There are lots of them, but have never been asked here, and will never be asked, and the reason is constant discouraging of people capable of asking them.

So how could I have presented this problem and solution in a way that would not have suffered this fate?

Comment: [Comments archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/152574/discussion-on-question-by-vividd-why-cant-i-be-working-on-my-night-moves).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question *here* to make it an actual question. And also added a badly needed Bob Seger reference. My skills are inadequate to do the same for your main-site question however.

Comment: @Shog9 All is well.

Comment: Related question: [Is it OK to promote my own code by self-answering my own questions?](/q/255509/5764553)

Answer (score 47):

There's no actual question there; there's a statement where the question should be.

There's a cool answer, but... No question. Unless you count the quoted "How many squares can a knight moving on an infinite chess board reach in N moves?" in which case it's off-topic (I find that you've asked *that* question [on the proper site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092952/king-and-knight-moving-on-an-infinite-chess-board) and it's done quite well... That should probably tell you something).

You're arguing that there's an *implicit* question, but that's always true - and the problem with implicit questions is that they tend to be too broad; *you* knew what you wanted, but if you hadn't posted your own answer who else would've? Too Broad and Unclear what you're asking are two sides of the same coin - [you're putting together a big puzzle without all the pieces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220).

This is one of the primary reasons why posting self-answered questions is so challenging: to do it effectively, you need not only a great answer, but to think back to when you *didn't* have a great answer and try to recreate the questions in your head at that time. To deconstruct your completed puzzle and lay the pieces out so that someone else facing the same paralyzing doubt can find their state of mind echoed in your question and from there arrive at your solution.

Comment: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601) :)

Answer (score 8):

> So how could I have presented this problem and solution in a way that would not have suffered this fate?

I don't believe that you can on Stack Overflow. Let me give it a few tries, keeping in mind that *the question must be judged by itself*, whether or not you self-answered.

> How do I use D3 to illustrate all the spaces that a chess knight can move to in *n* moves?

That would be seen as a "Give me teh codez plz" question and would have been closed as too broad. And it really is too broad. It's basically asking people to write a fairly large program in the answers.

> Here is my attempt at making a D3 illustration of the moves a chess knight can make *[code follows]* How can I improve this?

This *might* be okay on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). On SO, this has no specific problem or error, so either too broad, unclear, or off-topic > *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

---

Really, the underlying problem is that you *don't have* an underlying problem. You're just trying to show off a program you wrote. Stack Overflow just isn't the place for that. Put it on Github, Gitlab, SourceForge, or something and post a link on Hacker News. Or maybe post a link in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). But don't ask a question unless you *have* a question.

Back to your statement

> Where are interesting questions?

There are **many** sides to that particular debate. Since you're looking at it in terms of interesting questions that aren't allowed (rather than in terms of a deluge of bad questions flooding all the interesting questions away), I'll respond to it that way.

"Interesting" is not a good judge of things that are suitable for Stack Overflow. There are *many* things that are interesting but off topic.

- [What is the best IDE for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116292/5764553)
- [What is your best programming joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075/5764553)
- [I've found my software as cracked download on Internet, what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3550556/5764553)

Stack Overflow used to have a lot of these questions, but we've moved on. If you want to talk about that, I advise looking into the reasons:

- [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Keep in mind that many of the choices that were made back then are the reason that Stack Overflow is so heavily used by programmers today. If Stack Overflow had kept things open because they were popular, it would likely have slid into the depths of useless fun sites and some other, stricter programming site would have sprung up and all the programmers would have gone to it.

Because <strike>at the end of</strike> *in the middle of* the day, programmers need *answers*, not entertainment. Entertainment gets an unfair amount of attention and makes it harder for people to find answers to real questions.

That isn't to say that there isn't anything interesting on Stack Overflow. Just all the interesting stuff has to be on topic. There are these classics:

- [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5764553)
- [What is the “-->” operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/5764553)
- [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318911/5764553)

Those aren't kept open because they're interesting or popular. Those are all *good questions*. If you asked one of those today, <strike>it would be closed as a duplicate</strike> and it hadn't been asked before, it would be well-accepted.