# Why are answers to questions being closed as opinionated still acceptable as solution?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I usually tend to flag questions that imply some degree of opinionatedness (if such a term exists?!) and leave a reply why I feel that the post is likely ot attract opinionated answers. While I see such post rarly being closed as such (especially in the field of [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest)), I rarely create answers if the space in comments isn't enough to give enough hints. I know that I should refrain from such, though I feel that some of the problems arrise due to the lack of background knowledge of the asker and I don't want to let them die stupid (in a metaphorical sense).

Recenctly, though, I received an upvote as well as an accept as solution to a question that was already closed a couple of month ago and I was wondering why this is possible in first place.

The question itself was asking if a `PUT` request containing an empty JSON entity `{ }` should automatically delete the current representation or if it is ok to refuse such content in first place. While I feel that the question itself is specific enough and answerable by quoting the HTTP standard and as such on-topic, it got closed due to being likely to attract opinionated answers.

The close reason in more details states:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, **rather than facts, references, or specific expertise**.

My answer included a quote from the official [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) in regards to what a server should do on processing a `PUT` request. The standard itself leaves options to the implementor to actually decide whether a payload is verified first or not and to even transform the received representation to a totally different format. While the RFC discourages certain things, like a `GET`-payload and such, it does not prevent implementors to use such features. The only risk they might face though is the lack of interoperability then.

It is therefore debatable whether the close reason is actually correct, as the standard itself leaves such options to start with, though the actual question of this post here is more in regards to whether accepting an answer as solution if the question got closed for different reasons should be valid.

According to [SO's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.

which prevents people from answering such a question further until the question was modified in a way that is in line with the general guidelines.

By accepting an answer as solution it basically should help others with similar question in future. [SO defines accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer as such:

> Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Though without improvment of the question so it fits the mentioned guidelines, isn't such a move confusing to new users as SO does not want such questions on their platform in general?

What other reasons are there to allow accepting answers on questions that are closed as `primarily opinon-based` or the like?

---

As pointed out by [Redwald](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/545127/raedwald) this question seems to be similar to [that one here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable) though the suggested duplicate asks for `unanswerable` questions in the field of either `unclear what your are asking`, `lacks sufficient information` or `too broad` while this question, in an attempt to keep it as generic as possible, more or less faces the opposite corner. The referenced question also asks for if a question with an already accepted answer can be closed while this question targets whether a closed question should be able to accept an answer past it got closed. I therefore do not think that this question is a duplicate, but correct me if I'm wrong.

---

I am curious to know where these posts are duplicates. The referenced post includes the following question-statement:

> Can a question be legitimately closed using those reasons ("unclear what your are asking, lacks sufficient information and too broad") if it has answers?

and a title of

> Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable

where according to my understanding already an accepted answer existed **before** the post gets/got closed while I'm just asking the opposite. This question asks why someone is able to accept an answer **after** it got closed.

While the effect might be the same, a closed question with an accepted answer, they are different in nature.

Answer (score 7):

Closing a question for any reason doesn't render any answers that have been posted to it in the meantime suddenly useless, irrelevant or otherwise unusable to the asker or any other readers. As long as the question is not deleted, the answers are still there and remain as useful as ever.

Closing a question shouldn't, nor does it have to, prevent the asker from accepting an answer if one has already been posted, regardless of whether that answer demonstrates why the question is opinion-based by way of being an unsubstantiated opinion, or that answer defies the question being opinion-based by providing a purely factual answer (in some cases leading to the question being reopened afterward).

Comment: To me it feels a bit like a paradoxon. Having questions arround that shouldn't be their (in their unmodified version) and promoting answers to such unwanted questions even if they answer that question. Sure, some answers might invalidate the actual close reason (as pointed out in the duplicate suggestion), though in such cases the close could be removed first to allow accepting the answer.

Comment: To me, personally, allowing a question that was closed as opinionated to linger with answers on them, just encourages the behavior in the future.