# More emphasis given on not following a question format rather than the problem solving

Tags: discussion

It has happened multiple times that I post a question (that has enough information to solve the given problem) but people are quick to downvote the post because I missed something.

If there is missing information that might be needed, it can be asked in the comments and I can edit the question to clarify that but that is not what usually happens.

According to the website, the question is usually supposed to be downvoted when it shows clear lack of research on a said question and extremely poorly written questions.

But it has happened so many times that my question (that I usually ask as a last resort when my multiple ways to solve it doesn't work) gets downvoted not because it is unsolvable but because it does not stand up to a perfect format. I have received answers on such questions that actually talk about how to solve the problem and point out the mistake and explain things instead of pointing out what my question lacks.

My point is, if there are users who are able to solve my problem, my question isn't entirely a waste of space and effort.

I am not saying do not downvote a question that is obviously naïve. What I am saying is that if there is scope to improve a not an entirely wrong question, why do questions get downvoted?

It feels so discouraging because usually I post a question in hopes of suggestions as to how to solve my problem and the usual comments that might ask for clarifications but instead there are downvotes and comments that explain why my question is a wrong kind of question.

Again, I do understand there are questions that actually need pointing out wrong formats to help other users answer and save time but I feel like there are cases where the basic motto (which is people helping each other in a community) is overlooked in the process of criticising the way the question is asked.

Comment: From the Downvote Tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful (click again to undo)"*. If the question is missing information that is needed, it's unclear or not useful. That much is very simple to conclude. A question isn't useful if it can't be answered because there's information is missing, and a question is unclear is the missing information clarifies a specific point that is unwise ambiguous or very unclear. The fact that you are getting downvoted means that the information is **significant**. Perhaps a quick proof read before you submit?

Comment: How much time do you spend on crafting a question? And did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: You need to remember that Stack isn't build for *you*. But for **everyone else who comes after you with the same problem**. If your question doesn't contain enough information for people with the same issue to find it... for our purpose, *it's not a good question*. It takes a mind shift to get to that.... but it's the best way to get a better reception on Stack. Remember how useful to **future** visitors it has to be (note: I personally leave questions in draft for a week as I work on them, research, polish, etc. I rarely ask questions cause a week usually solves my issue...)

Comment: But there are other users who are able to anser my question?

Comment: Yes, I do downvote. But, if the OP makes proper edits and pings me, I make sure to remove the vote, and even convert it to an upvote as appropriate.

Comment: @bobthebuilder maybe they guessed? Maybe they answered because they know enough to be able to *assume* the piece you're missing? Maybe their answer contains two solutions, one based on each assumption? "someone can answer it" isn't a good enough argument, since the fact it got downvoted can also mean "someone can't understand it"....

Comment: *"But there are other users who are able to anser my question?"* And sometimes, when people guess these answer, they actually make the problem **worse**. People not putting the effort in to make sure they supply all the information (therefore ask a low quality question) and get answers that answer the possible problem just "promotes" people being lazy with their questions. It's also why I really think that less "care" should be given ny "roomba" if a severely downvoted quoted has an accepted answer.

Comment: Provide us some examples, please. It would be a good way to discover what's wrong in the downvoted question (we might even admit that they were indeed good questions, who knows...). PS: it is not encouraging the fact that the question complaining about downvotes on your question... did not provide _a minimum reproducible example_ ...

Comment: related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: The way to help you (not that helping just you is the long term goal) is not to debug, rewrite & test your code for you but to get you to reason, communicate & act effectively in coding, debugging & asking. And that's what getting you to ask good questions via question votes, close votes & comments is doing. As is answering good questions. PS Try to identify exactly what the question is supposed to be in your last question post--which doesn't actually ask a question--& exactly what an answer would entail.

Answer (score 3):

I dare to speculate that the downvotes and the missing information were unrelated.

It's easy to accuse the people that left the comments that they are the downvoters, since other viewers are not so visible, but if you look at the view count of your question I suspect that this number will be a (large) multiple of the downvotes.

The most likely scenario is that the people that commented were trying to be helpful, and the downvotes were for unrelated issues. Usual reasons are:

- they thought you didn't research the topic sufficiently before asking
- they have seen that or similar questions a million times already, and they got tired of it.
- they saw a huge code dump, instead of a minimal example

And probably many more that I haven't though of.