# What does this question mean?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, english, grammatical-correction

The title is *[Check if every other element in list is even?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393877/checking-if-all-even-indexed-elements-in-a-zero-based-indexed-list-are-even)*, and the body contains a longer version of that:

> I [...] want to make a function that checks if every other (all positive indexes inc 0) integer in a list is even.

It literally doesn't make any logical sense to me. It reads *every other*, but no other element of the list is mentioned before that point of the sentence.

On the other hand, a later part of the question reads (my emphasis)

> However this seems to always give true as long as the last *even position* in the list is *even*

which makes me think that *every other* was meant to be *every <s>other</s> **odd***. And this makes me think that I should simply edit the question.

However, since both answers seem to address the question just like it reads *every odd*, even if I haven't applied the correction yet, I wonder if I just ignore this math-specific use of the word *other* in English?

Furthermore, even if I am correct, then also the part in the parenthesis (*all positive indexes inc 0*) needs a correction, as it should be *all <s>positive</s> **odd** indexes inc 0*.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the OP for clarification in a comment?

Comment: @BSMP, ok, got your point.

Comment: @BSMP Zero is even.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I agree, but I think BSMP's main point is that on 0-based indexing, indexes 0, 2, 4, 6, ... are actually the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, ... So it's confusing to address them by parity.

Comment: If you find a question to be completely unclear, such that you cannot make heads or tails of it in an edit, then you should **vote to close the question as unclear**.

Comment: @Enrico Ah, very good point!

Comment: @CodyGray, come on, other two users have answered it, and the OP also thanked one of them. I'm just asking if that way using _other_ is appropriate in English-math or not.

Comment: I don't know why the fact that two other users have answered it is *at all* relevant. Other people's actions shouldn't constrain yours. If you think the question is fundamentally unclear, then either (A) you do not have the domain knowledge to understand the question (which is possible, but if you thought this was the case, you wouldn't have come to ask about it on Meta), or (B) you should be voting to close the question as unclear. The vote doesn't mean "I think it might be unclear to someone else". It means, "This question is fundamentally unclear to me, and I cannot fix it."

Comment: I disagree on the relevance of the other answers, @CodyGray. I'm not a native speaker, and looking at two answers which illuminate me on what probably the question means is enough for me to make the hypothesis that maybe there's some gap in my English, and this question here on meta is to understand if this is the case.

Comment: @CodyGray _“I don't know why the fact that two other users have answered it is at all relevant”_ — The fact that they (mis-)understood the question in the same way is relevant.

Comment: see [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: ["Every other"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary&oq=dictionary+&ie=UTF-8#dobs=every%20other) means alternating elements in a sequence.

Comment: it is a good question and the solution is quite easy to realize in almst every programming language, nthing is unclear at all,

Comment: @nbk, are you referring to the original question or to the one it is now?

Comment: @khelwood, thank you very much, I guess yours is the true answer to my question, so feel free to write it in an answer and I'll accept it; or I'll do it in a few days. I absolutely did not know that. Luckily, my edit doesn't change the intended meaning of the original question.

Comment: @Enrico the wording of the original question was poor, but it was much improved, but still it was a good question, with everything a question needs.

Comment: Yeah, @nkb. But to me it sounded meaningless, because I did not know what khelwood made me aware of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["Every other"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary&oq=dictionary+&ie=UTF-8#dobs=every%20other) means alternating elements of a sequence.

Comment: Red, blue, red, blue, red, blue, red, blue. Every other element is blue.

Answer (score 6):

For me the question is poorly worded, but it is an interesting question on why some piece of code is not working as wanted. However the question can be understood and two people have answered it. I do not know Haskell, but have used another functional language so and I can see why the code fails and why the two answers work.

The idea of Stack Overflow is to make a repository of good questions with good answers. If you feel a question can be improved then feel free to edit it to make it better. Not knowing Haskell means I will not edit it in case I misunderstand some Haskell details. If you do not want to edit it then consider adding a comments suggesting improvements that the originator of the question, or another topic expert, can make.