# Why is my question about extending Java classes that implement an interface unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, unclear

I recently asked the following question on Stack Overflow:

[Extend three classes that implements an interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163624/extend-three-classes-that-implements-an-interface-in-java)

It was closed by three different people as being unclear, but the people who had answered and commented clearly understood it.

Why was my question marked as unclear? Is there any way that I can edit it to improve the clarity?

Comment: You could start by adressing the assumptions of commenters in an update to your question. Adress their remarks. An edited question will then enter the review queue.

Comment: People responding are clearly _attempting_ to understand it. Because it is unclear.

Comment: @ModusTollens They are not unclear to me. it's not my problem if some readers lack the necessary domain knowledge to understand a question and its answers. And that is certainly not a reason to close it or downvote it.

Comment: @EmLi Yes, it is. It is in your own best interest to make the question as clear as possible. It's also good to not waste the time of others by making them guess. If you want your question reopened, please edit it.

Comment: Usual "those people with gold badges in the Java have no idea what this Java question about interfaces and inheritance is"...  If 3 people with gold badges in Java acted on your question and did not find it clear enough you may want to at least consider that there is something indeed missing in the question... I'd start with "this fees really clumsy and ugly. Is there a better way?" which is *never* a good explanation of what you want to improve specifically.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov for the sake of precision, only two close voters have gold badge in this tag. Third voter has "only" bronze badge in Java. :) If seriously, this closure looks quite authoritative: all voters together have got at least 2100 upvotes for their answers in at least 420 Java questions

Comment: It's worth noting that the author of something (whether it's a question, an answer or something anywhere else in life) is the pretty much the *worst* judge of whether something is clear or not.

Comment: There is one answer on your post, where two people argue 'OP didn't ask that, they asked this'. Isn't that a good indication your question actually **isn't** clear? In any case..... You don't really make a strong point or argument here... Just saying 'its clear'

Comment: @Patrice Actually, there are two answers, one has been deleted by the author. That answer also misunderstood the question on certain parts, thus agreeing with your argument that the mere existence of an answer post doesn't imply that the question is clear and understandable.

Comment: “it's not my problem if some readers lack the necessary domain knowledge to understand a question and its answers.” - It sort of is your problem.  Your question was closed by those readers.  You also don’t have the domain knowledge to answer your own question.  So perhaps clarifying your question would help everyone involved.

Comment: **Moderator Note: Stop deleting questions that are under active discussion on Meta!** Since I cannot lock the questions to prevent deletion (as that would prevent edits, votes, etc., all of which I want to continue to allow), and I cannot selectively revoke deletion privileges, my only recourse is to suspend the accounts of the repeat offenders voting for deletion. Consider this your warning.

Answer (score 10):

First, note that it is [not a logical contradiction to close a question as "unclear", just because a question has been answered or commented upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable). It is entirely possible that some of the commenters and/or answerers made *assumptions* when attempting to respond to your question. The need to make assumptions is what makes a question unclear.

Furthermore, I want to highlight a couple of points that were made in the comments. First, various commenters have noted that your question was closed by people who have a great deal of familiarity with Java, so it is entirely unfair to represent their close votes as anything less than genuine.

Next, a gem by Jon Skeet, reminding you to consider your own bias when judging the clarity of your own content:

> It's worth noting that the author of something (whether it's a question, an answer or something anywhere else in life) is the pretty much the *worst* judge of whether something is clear or not.
>
> – Jon Skeet

In light of these points, please mind your tone in the future. Coming to Meta and just *declaring* that your question is not unclear is not very persuasive. It sets you up on a collision course with everyone who believes in the function of our community moderation. And it's just…not an argument. Your question was closed, which puts the burden of proof on you to defend it or fix it. We're happy to *help* you, but blaming us doesn't really help resolve the situation.

---

**That said**, I don't think your question is unclear. It might have some *technical* issues, but there's nothing unclear about what is being asked. I've discussed with a couple of other people who write Java rather than just drinking it, and they agreed that there's enough information there to understand what you are trying to accomplish. So, while it *might* be the case that the question needs to be closed for a different reason, I'm going to take a stand that it is *not* unclear, and that that was a poor choice of close reasons. **I've re-opened your question.**

It's also been pointed out to me—and I agree—that what you've brought up in your question is a practical programming problem, reflecting a situation that is not uncommon, and that it poses a bit of a challenge to solve in an elegant way. By my standards, these are the types of questions we *want* on Stack Overflow, rather than just endless "debug my code" sessions.

If some Java subject-matter experts want to disagree with me on the acceptability of this question, they're welcome to do so, but they'll need to provide some actual arguments. The answer box awaits.

Comment: I'm one of the commenters under that question who tried to get more details out of the OP but I also don't think the question lacks enough details to be closed for that reason. I didn't vote to close it but I can understand why one would: The question asks about A and an answer to A is definitely possible. However, it could be that the OP actually had A+ in mind and it seems pretty obvious to me. An answerer has to answer A and A+. It's about the actual use case of the classes, e.g.: "How are the classes together with the solution supposed to be used?", which reveals the *best* solution.

Comment: @akuzminykh Even if we don't know the use case, it's answerable. Perhaps even more so, as the answers are not limited to one specific use case. I liked your proposal in comments. I wish you'd made it into an Answer.