# How can I improve the way I use SO and avoid downvoting of some of my posts?

Tags: discussion, support, new-users

I am new on Stack Overflow and getting used to the platform and community. I have used it a couple of times when I discovered the answer to a question I was struggling with, and for which no answer was available on Stack Overflow.

I do this for two reasons:

1. SO is simply the place where I tend to look first for answers; and
2. I would like to avoid someone else wasting time on the same question

But it looks like my way of using Stack Overflow is not being appreciated, because I notice downvotes on some of my posts:

- [Architect / StatET: Launching R Console was cancelled because R engine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670733/architect-statet-launching-r-console-was-cancelled-because-r-engine-failed)
- [.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava' when installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941797/onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava-when-installing-a-package)

So I was wondering: could I get some advice from the community on how I could improve my use of Stack Overflow?

Comment: The first link _may_ have been downvoted by someone that doesn't like self-answered questions. The question and answer are of sufficient quality, though. The second link on the other hand, is not much more than a code / error message dump. I'd try to improve it by adding some details, where you can.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.

Comment: @Adi: In general, I don't worry about 1 downvote in the presence of upvotes, some downvote appear "randomly" (honestly, I sometimes wonder if people do not simply click on the wrong arrow). I start to worry when I get a second downvote (unless it's otherwise massively upvoted).

Comment: There are some people on this site who think that self answered questions are "gaming the system". Personally, these two links couldn't prove them more wrong

Comment: @Sammaye, You can't blame them, there'll always be people who think self-answered questions are gaming-the-system. The only way to stop it is to include a  direct link to [*"it is **explicitly encouraged** to ask and answer your own question"*](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) right at the top of each self-answered thread.

Comment: You've got 1/10 my rep, more votes on your highest-voted question, and almost as many votes on your highest-voted answer. This definitely doesn't look like the account of someone who has upset the community with their bad use of the site. I think your self-evaluation is overly harsh!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: He didn't have that many votes on that question / answer before this meta post. He got 379 rep in the last 2 days, as result of the Meta effect.

Comment: Meta-effect in effect. These kind of questions bring nothing to the table.

Comment: Pity repping does seem to be a trend. I guess I'd rather have that than vengeance/justice downvoting.

Comment: Just to be clear: if I see a post like this while reviewing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085722/how-to-count-all-of-the-likes-and-comments-in-a-facebook-photo-album#comment52067350_32085722 should I ask the poster to turn his question-that-contains-an-answer into a seperate question and answer?

Comment: Regarding self-answered questions, some users (such as myself) find them fine only as long as the question was sincerely asked. A self-answer that appears five seconds after the question was posted is basically using SO as your personal blog. Some questions aren't generalizable to more than a single person (the asker), but if you found the information you needed by yourself, the question won't even benefit that single person. When someone actually runs into a similar problem and can't solve it, they'll ask a question themselves, Just In Time. Let them.

Comment: And now you've meta-effected yourself several hundred rep points for those blog posts, so you've definitely come out ahead.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: SO actively encourages users to answer the question immediately when writing the question itself, so the Q and A get posted at the _same_ time. I couldn't disagree more with your comment.

Comment: @Cerbrus - SO should encourage _other users_ to immediately answer a question. Immediate self-answers mean that every other programmer either A) doesn't care about that issue, or B) has managed to solve that issue themselves. At that point, what's the point of that question's presence on SO? Nothing. If, at some point in the future, someone _actually encounters that issue and cannot solve it_, they can post a question themselves. I don't approve of this sort of preemptive strike. It is, by definition, not needed.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: If a users encounters a difficult problem that he manages to solve, and writes a _good_ question and answer about it, then that is a _valuable addition_ to the site, since it can be used for future visitors. For example, [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852389/how-do-i-use-the-c6-using-static-feature) of mine wasn't asked yet, and _has_ been positively received. Future visitors _can_ benefit from that question when searching for that problem. There is ___nothing___ wrong with self-answered questions, provided they're written well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Are you even aware that there is a "Answer your own question" field, when writing a question? So the Question and answer get posted at the exact same time. You can only accept your own answer after 2 days, though, so there is _plenty_ of time for other users to answer it, too.

Comment: If the future visitors are interested in that topic, they can ask about it. That's the whole point, isn't it? Why are we interested in storing knowledge that currently _benefits no one, not even the asker_?

Comment: If it benefits _no one_, users will downvote it. Your assumption that self-answered questions pose no benefit to anyone is simply irrational. The point of SO is to build a knowledge base that users can find answers to their questions in, preferably without having to ask the question. ___Every___ user should search before asking. Self-answered questions can be very valuable search results, as usually, people answering their own questions are experts on the subject.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Yes, I'm 100% aware of it and fine with it - as long as it isn't immediate. If someone can't resolve their issue, posts a question, and then some time later does manage to figure it out themselves, a self-answer is fine. After all, they were sufficiently stuck that they felt they had to ask a question. My beef with this is that these immediate self-answerers _were never so stuck with their issue that they had to ask a question_, as evidenced by their lack of a prior question.

Comment: Let's put it this way. SO [officially encourages people to answer their own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Users could've been working on an answer for ___days___ before posting anything about it. _"were never so stuck with"_ is yet another assumption that's simply ___incorrect___.

Comment: Basically, to me, immediate self-answers are "that was a unique challenge I just faced. I think I'll repost it on my blog that SO hosts for me." And, again, I find there to be a HUGE difference between any old self-answer and an _immediate_ self-answer. An immediate self-answer says that the asker didn't get stuck. Maybe no one else will get stuck with that issue either. If they do get stuck... they can ask a question.

Comment: And advertising those questions on meta for a ton of meta-effect rep is basically getting people who wouldn't normally care about a post to cancel out the votes of users who actually cared enough to vote, which is [_not_ actively encouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes).

Comment: Posting an immediate self-answer also heavily implies that the asker is sure that, although they solved their issue with a bit of research and ingenuity, everyone else is too dumb to figure it out for themselves and would benefit from being spoon-fed an answer... an answer which, thus far, no one has cared enough to ask for. I think it's rude, and I don't agree with this practice at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 An immediate self-answer says ___nothing___ about how difficult the problem was, for the user. The answer could be based on days of research, trial and error. You continuously ignore my arguments against your assumptions, so I'll just end this discussion.

Comment: _"Everyone else is too dumb"_ Another assumption. Wanting to help future visitors with the same problem =/= "everyone else"

Comment: So... maybe everyone else will go through days of trial and error to find the answer. But, if they can't manage it (or simply don't have the patience for it), they can ask a question. I don't see why we assume that only the immediate self-answerer is capable of such efforts. And how do we know there will be future visitors with the same problem? There haven't been any thus far, and there still aren't, because the immediate self-answerer doesn't need their own answer at that point. When the answer is _actually needed_, it can be asked for.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 To be honest, I'm more annoyed that everyone upvoted these without bothering to investigate whether they were good questions/answers at all. And that the answer saying, "You've done nothing wrong!" has over 100 upvotes when it took me about 15 minutes to identify legitimate problems even when I'm not an expert in any of the technologies. A quick Google search on the error in the second one is all you need to see that not enough research was done (or at the least, wasn't included in the question).

Comment: @jpmc26 - Even worse, the impact on this particular user's rep has been enormous, as all their posts besides these self-answers have been two answers with a net of zero votes and one question with a net of -4 votes (duplicate), putting him at 21 rep prior to this. So now, because he complained on meta that people downvoted his poorly-researched blog posts, he has the approximate rep and privileges of a user who's posted one or two dozen good answers. I think people forget that main site votes don't mean "I agree with you on principle" like meta votes do.

Comment: Hmm, something fishy!!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your use of Stack Overflow is just fine. It's long established that [self-answers are a good thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).

From what I can see, both your questions deal with a specific problem, show sufficient effort, clear enough with both the problem and what was tried to solve it, as well as the answers.

So, keep it up. There would always be those who downvote, and some people don't like self-answers for some reason, although it's well established that they're encouraged. Don't let it discourage you.

Comment: Self-answers are also good, as long as they are detailed. Sometimes I see self-answers that just reveal OP found a typo. Those questions (completely) should be removed. I have answered my own questions, and provided every step to ensure that anyone else with a remotely similar issue can find help from it.

Comment: Can people who downvote good self-answers please explain why they do this?

Comment: @Persijn: Don't count on it.

Comment: Why they provide self-answers?  To benefit those that might land themselves in a similar bind in the future.  It will save them a (likely) significant amount of research and a good amount of trial and error.

Comment: @user2366842 No, why they downvote good self-answers.

Comment: oh...right.  Sorry lack of sleep kicked in.

Comment: @user2366842 Also, i document the issue for the time time it happens to me :)

Comment: @Persijn Other than the "oh, the problem was related to something else entirely" type of self answers, I find that a good number of self answers are a case of the OP is looking for an excuse to answer a question no one would ever ask.  Compare [this self answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193029/sass-each-loops-in-scss) to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593476/modifying-the-middle-of-a-selector-in-sass-adding-removing-classes-etc)

Answer (score 2):

I really hate when people dismiss downvotes so readily. Even if most people wouldn't agree, with *most* downvote cases, I can (with a little thought) come up with *some* kind of explanation for what the downvoter might have been thinking.

For the first, my guess is that the answer appears to be a copy/paste of a response you received from a company. Before I say anything else, I'm not certain of how licensing and copyright might affect what content you can and cannot take from the response and place on a StackOverflow answer. Ask another question to get clarification there, and possibly try to obtain permission from the company. Assuming that you can post the content legally, the answer would be much better if you reformulated it into your own words and presented the information directly. Among other problems, the answer as it stands has extra fluff like, "We are working hard on a solution." While I commend you for going to the effort of sharing this information with us, copy/pasting an e-mail response from them without cleaning it up to SO standards is poor style at best.

For the second, I can't come up with much within the answer itself, but Googling for "r install package" plus your error message (`LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`) turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311107/build-r-package-failing-with-rjava-loadlibrary-not-a-valid-win32-application-f) pretty readily. So I suspect this is a common problem and that there's already answers to it floating around. The downvote is probably because the solution to your problem can be found on any number of other answers or websites.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? I can't see how the issues I raise are illegitimate as problems.

Comment: Not me, but your first paragraph sorta missed the mark. People don't dismiss downvotes, but **silent downvotes**. The reason for that is..... .... well, I think you've just figured it out yourself.

Answer (score -67):

Negative votes are caused due to reasons that vary from a wide range like

1. Spelling mistakes and silly shorthand **sms** type mistakes like using *(i am)* instead of *(I am)*, or (*u wil b*) instead of (*you will be*)
2. *Grammatical Mistakes* and  not using *capital* letter for the first letter
   of the sentence,
3. Having *technical* or *logical error* in your query.
4. *Less/no effort* applied to find your answers.
5. *Less/no effort* on the code samples you have provided, etc.
6. Providing codes in your questions/answers, but not highlighting them using
   *Ctrl+K*.
7. Using Fluffs like "*Thanks*", "*Please, anybody help me*", etc.
8. Begging like "*Please, help me. I would be grateful*".
9. You asked something on meta, giving links as reference. By doing
   so, you have drawn everybody's attention. Embrace yourself because now you
   will receive more downpour of negative points. That's called "**Meta
   Effect**".
10. Having a question posted, without displaying any optimum amount of
     effort causes downvotes. This states that you haven't put much effort. As such
     people will consider you as a "**Help Vampire**".
11. Please make some search before posting any question. If any
     question(already existing) matches your question, people will
     definitely downvote you because your question will be considered a **duplicate** one.
12. Using **noise** in your questions by making words **bold**(to *highlight* or
     put *emphasis* on the word) causes more downvotes. If no. of bold
     words are more, definitely these are considered noise. Less no. of bold words, and they are not considered as noise. Example: See how I use bold words in this answer.
13. *Abusive* or *rude* comments in answers/question.
14. Don't *debate* or *argue*(especially if you have low points) too much. Arguments
     often can lead to vindictive mentality and people may give you 
     downvotes.
15. Never complain or ask why you have been downvoted. This will cause
     more downvotes.
16. Lastly, all the above stated points happened with me. So I decided
     to stay *silent* in any type of issues, if ever happens.

Comment: _"Using noise in your questions by making words bold(to highlight or put emphasis on the word) causes more downvotes."_ Isn't that ironic?

Comment: How is that ironic? Would you like to explain?

Comment: Downvoting because this answer has too much focus on the "Meta" effect, and it's a generic _"Questions can be downvoted because of X"_ post. This answer, especially it's last 2 points, read like the answerer feels he unjustly got downvoted too often.

Comment: It's ironic because you're using __bold__ and _italics_ quite a lot in your answer.

Comment: I stated "*If no. of bold words are more, definitely these are considered noise. Less no. of bold words, and they are not considered as noise.*". Total no. of bold words in an answer having 15 points is 6. Still it's noise. OP will learn it. Thanks. :)

Comment: It's not the number that counts, it's how you use them.

Comment: Still, I just used them to lay emphasis on the needed words. Whatever happens, OP is learning from my mistakes. :)

Comment: @Saswat The OP didn't come anywhere near close to making your mistakes.

Comment: When did I say OP made the same mistakes? I just stated the reasons. Reasons that have wide range of variety. @TZHX

Comment: And that have no relevance to this question. You don't seem to actually be following point 16.

Comment: I am just trying to learn from my mistakes. That's why I am asking you. I hope I am not offending anybody. I am trying to be polite as much as I can. Have I been rude to anybody? If so, I heartily apologize then.

Comment: i dont understand why this answer gets so many down votes?, is people tryting to match both post with the same up and down votes?

Comment: @Tim: Because, as TZHX said, it has no relevance to this question whatsoever - exactly none of these points applies to the question at hand, even if they hold true in general.

Comment: this is not really an answer that applies to Adi, it seems like just a rant for all YOU feel like you got downvoted for....

Comment: *Don't debate or argue (especially if you have low points) too much.* — I don't understand this mentality. Why would you care about these points when you have your point of view? Argue and let people prove you're wrong and learn from it, or prove you're right using good sources and your logic.

Comment: @Mark, what happens if your points get below 3000? You will loose some facility.

Comment: @Saswat Well, once you have 50 points (comment anywhere) all the 'facility' you get is really only for *moderating* the site (the last priveledge being granted at 20k, not 3). It doesn't affect your use of the site

Comment: Half of these are total rubbish - things like spelling mistakes, bad formatting and general fluff will not get you a non-trivial amount of downvotes. The existence of a duplicate will only get you downvotes if it takes someone less than 10 seconds to find. There's nothing wrong with disagreeing, unless you're being nasty about it or it's about the rules of the site. If you made a decent attempt to try to figure out what's wrong with your question, I doubt you'll get downvotes from posting on Meta.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yeah, it's just that those first three things, when bad enough, often correlate with poor research or otherwise poor asking skills.

Comment: @Cerbrus, That's actually called "demonstrating the point". It'll be called *ironic* when  people downvote this answer due to the bolded words, yet by doing so, they're proving him correct.

Comment: @Pacerier: Looking at the quality of this answer, I doubt the use of bold / italics was intentional, to prove a point.

Comment: @Pacerier that's a great point. I just made a question here, and points 14 and 15 seem fitting. Your point also shows that some users (me at least, and op seems as well) are actually afraid to ask questions and debate about then, because of huge backlash. I just got a question deleted because of that, so, there's that. And all these are not rubbish - I saw plenty of debate here in Meta about bad grammar being reason for downvoting, deleting questions, ranting of users, and such. Point 16  is fitting as well. Look at the backlash he received, because of some bold, that could be editted out.

Comment: @Malavos he's getting a backlash here because this is virtually a rant answer where he doesn't bring anything to the table (out of his 16 points, not ONE is relevant to the OP's situation). But yes, what you describe is the "meta effect". Not necessarily backlash. If you bring a bad question to meta, a LOT more people who care about quality will see it, incurring you downvotes and close votes. If you bring a GOOD question to meta, the opposite might happen (I don't know your exact situation so I can't say if that's what happened to you though)

Comment: @Patrice My situation is not the point here - What I wanted to say is that this kind of reaction is pure prejudice - Will this backlash improve the way Saswat answer here, or in any SE site? I doubt it - it just showed him that he's right - he got a lot of negative votes over "simple things" (this is debatable, alright), but this answer could be easily edited to remove the Bolding, and someone could comment on show him how that's bad. But the attitude was just to poke, give negative votes, and move on.

See my point? There's no improvement here, just the making of a bad image of the network.

Comment: @Malavos it's not backlash (unless he got DVed on the main site, which is a shame if that happened). In the main site, if you come in and give an answer unrelated to the question, what happens? This is the same. His points have no place here, so it's a bad answer. I get your point that the community COULD be a little bit more friendly, especially on meta. But are you aware of how many relatively new users come here ONLY fighting and not trying to learn? arguably some people get tired and get cranky because of that. Not necessarily saying it's justified, just explaining

Comment: @Malavos Patrice's point is that it's not the use of formatting in this answer that got it downvotes, it's that the answer reads as a rant and not an answer to the question asked. That's been explained in the comments on this answer already, so is Saswat wants to fix their answer, they can take that feedback into account and fix their answer. Several people on this comment thread have mentioned that 1) this answer reads as a rant and 2) the questions linked by the OP hit _none_ of these points, so this answer really doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Patrice and my point here is that, specially in meta, specially in a answer regarding the topic, this should be treated! This is the place where they come to improve, no? Cleary the answerer and op ARE trying something. And it's clear that more than 50 people got tired and cranky.  This answer got more votes and interactions than the question.

If all these voters focused on to improve this answer, both op, and Saswat, and even me, who is looking to improve, would benefit. This cranky temperament you speak of should not be tolerated. (in my point of view)

Comment: @Malavos I'm with you on that. Now are you aware that for each user like you who tries to improve, we have 5, 10, maybe 15 other users coming in and kicking back on EVERYTHING they get told. There's a point where, if there's 100 times more people who don't care about quality, you can't take an hour to explain to each of them. Saswat had a FULL post about fluff and grammar mistakes, where a LOT of explanations was given to him. That post was HIGHLY active for at least 2 hours, giving him a LOT of info. Why he deleted it? no clue.

Comment: @Kendra I do not see this as a rant, sorry. I see it as a discussion point. Shouldn't we remove rant completely, if so?

Comment: @Malavos, truly to say, my answer over here, is the best example of a bad answer(either in context of ranting, or grammatical issues, or bad English, etc). This is the best example to demonstrate how bad answers are received by others. This answer was made particularly bad to let newcomers know what they should learn.

Comment: @Saswat, Patrice, nice points. And I do believe this is a problem. We (I include in this, of course) are making newcomers receive the site badly. Saswat, your answer is indeed bad, but I do not think it deserves such actions as -50. I'm not arguing it's a bad answer, I want to bring to the table that there are reactions more.. proper for such things. Anyway, I should be working. I think Adi has learned a lot in this discussion (me too)

Comment: @Malavos If you don't read it as a rant, then don't downvote it. Simple as that. I haven't downvoted the answer myself, as I feel there _is_ some useful information in it, but it also does not relate to the question at hand as the OP really hasn't run into any of the real points in this list. (Some of the points in the list really aren't a thing as they are stated, at least not from the evidence I've seen.) Several of us have seen some of Saswat's other meta posts here recently, and several of those have been downvoted for various reasons. This answer, in that context, reads as a rant on that.

Comment: @Kendra so should we look into a user's past question to assert the current answer quality and if it fits in the site?

Don't get me wrong, but I do not think that's the way. Shouldn't we be judging each answer as it's own? A user can change, and if we look at his background to reason our vote, we are making a mistake, no?

Comment: @Kendra, yes I admit. Even the aftereffect impacted another answer given by me on meta.

Comment: @Malavos I'm not saying that. I'm just saying that some of us already, by naturally finding the posts, understood this answer as a rant due to Saswat's past Meta posts and how they were received. It's not being taken in context of _Saswat,_ but instead in context of how his past posts have been received. If they had written this with an excellent post history on Meta, it really still would've been downvoted as none of the points are relevant here.

Comment: Saswat, I've actually read the other answer and I think the issue there was your wording. I had to read it a few times to understand it. I would edit to help make it a little more clear for you, but I don't have the rep to edit on Meta. (Unless a post is community wiki, you need 2k rep to edit on Meta. There are no suggested edits.) I originally read that answer as suggesting the second scenario you listed being completely appropriate. When I re-read it, I saw you meant that was _not_ an acceptable time to ask a new question. That answer was even when I looked earlier, at least.

Comment: Can you explain which portion you find difficult to understand? I have a bad habit of using extended sentences. I think you felt difficulty with that.

Comment: It wasn't that I found it hard to understand, it's that I misread it because of how you have it structured. When I get time here in a bit, I'll comment on it for you to give you a couple suggestions to make it a little clearer. :)

Comment: Ok, :) that will help me a lot. @Kendra. Thanks

Comment: @Kendra just a question - let's say a user indeed post a rant - "ARRRRR my question was deleted! DAKKA DAKKA DAKKA" and things like that. Should we delete it entirely?

Comment: @Malavos: _Yes_.

Comment: @Malavos Normally when such a post happens, the rant gets edited out and then people try to talk it through. But a poster coming here with such a post will NOT be opened to discussion, so in the end, it will be closed, indeed. RARELY, I've seen very aggravated users understand they need to calm down. But this is about as rare as a unicorn

Comment: @Malavos It usually at least gets closed and downvoted to oblivion. There are some rant questions that are _asked_ as a rant, but they end up provoking useful and helpful discussion. Rants actually _do_ get posted on Meta, usually by newer users who don't fully understand what SO is about. Sometimes these rants are written in such a way that, despite being a rant, they really generate a useful and productive discussion about the issue in general. (There's an example of one of these somewhere, but I can't remember what it was. I've only seen the one really good example though.)

Comment: Is it just me or have there been even more down-votes on any other answer here?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: this answer isn't even close. I don't have the link readily available though.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites